# How do magic \dots work in amsmath?

Tags: macros, amsmath

The [`amsmath`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package redefines the `\dots` command so that it "guesses" the correct height of the dots with respect to its context. For example

```
$x, \dots, y$
```

will produce three lowered dots, aligned with the commas. While

```
$x \to \dots \to y$
```

uses centered dots that align with the arrows. However, if I define my own macros, `amsmath` can no longer guess and it always uses the lowered dots. For example

```
\newcommand{\myto}{\to}
$x \myto \dots \myto y$
```

uses the wrong dots. How can I tell `amsmath` that I want centered and not lowered dots?

Btw., I know about `\cdots` but what I want is `\dots` to still be able to guess the correct ones automatically.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Looking at `amsmath.sty`, I see lots of lines like:

```
\gdef\coprod{\DOTSB\coprod@\slimits@}
```

I would guess that the `\DOTSB` controls what kind of dots go before (or after?) this symbol.  Doing

```
\show\mapsto
```

shows that that has the magic `\DOTSB`.  So if defining your own macro, I would experiment with adding `\DOTSB`, `\DOTSI`, `\DOTSX` (those appear to be the options) before or after them.  (Please report back on what happens!).  I would guess that `\dots` "knows" about certain commands, but has to be told about any extra.  `\to` seems to come in under the "known" commands, but, for example, it has to be told about `\mapsto`:

```
> \mapsto=\long macro:
->\DOTSB \mapstochar \rightarrow .
l.3 \show\mapsto
```

Comment: If this is possible, I didn't know about it. (Sorry, no time to check myself right now.) Very interesting!

Comment: Just a quick note before going to sleep: it works! If I use `\newcommand{\myto}{\DOTSB\to}` then `\myto` will produce the correct alignment! Thanks, tomorrow I'll try and check what the other options do.

Answer (score 10):

This doesn't do what you're asking for, but in best semantic fashion, amsmath also defines

> - `\dotsc` for “dots with commas”
> - `\dotsb` for “dots with binary operators/relations”
> - `\dotsm` for “multiplication dots”
> - `\dotsi` for “dots with integrals”
> - `\dotso` for “other dots” (none of the above)

(Quoted from [the Short Math Guide for LaTeX, page 15](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/short-math-guide/short-math-guide.pdf#page=15).)  Each of these specifies the height.  I didn't find the behavior of \dots you described documented.  Can you point out where it is?

Comment: Thanks, I already knew about these, but I'm actually trying to define a macro that will add `\dots` between some some relations/operators which are provided by the user. So I, as a package write, don't know in advance which of the semantic commands should be used. However, as the example in the question shows, `amsmath` somehow knows!

Answer (score 5):

OK, so since I asked the [debugging](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538/how-to-best-debug-latex) question, I ventured out and tried to debug!

Using just `\show` didn't work, producing the following in the log file:

```
> \dots=macro:
->\protect \dots  .
l.7 \show\dots
```

so I googled for the show command and found [this](http://texfaq.org/FAQ-ltxcmds) page and so I did the following

```
\def\pshow#1{{\let\protect\show #1}}
\begin{equation*}
 a \pshow{\dots} b=0;
\end{equation*}
```

which resulted in:

```
> \dots =\long macro:
->\ifmmode \@xp \mdots@ \else \@xp \textellipsis \fi .
\dots ->\protect \dots
```

Looking deeper to examine `\mdots@` is possible (using `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`) but is quite horrific:

```
 > \mdots@=macro:
->\FN@ \mdots@@ .
l.11 \show\mdots@
```

where

```
> \FN@=macro:
->\futurelet \@let@token .
```

and

```
> \mdots@@=macro:
->\gdef \thedots@ {\dotso@ }\ifx \@let@token \boldsymbol \gdef \thedots@ \boldsymbol {\boldsymboldots@ }\else \ifx ,\@let@token \gdef \thedots@ {\dotsc }\else \ifx \not \@let@token \gdef \thedots@ {\dotsb@ }\else \keybin@ \ifgtest@ \gdef \thedots@ {\dotsb@ }\else \xdef \meaning@ {\meaning \@let@token ..........}\xdef \meaning@@ {\meaning@ }\@xp \math@ \meaning@ \math@ \ifgtest@ \@xp \mathch@ \meaning@ \mathch@ \ifgtest@ \@xp \getmathch@ \meaning@ \getmathch@ \fi \else \@xp \macro@ \meaning@@ \macro@ \ifgtest@ \@xp \not@ \meaning@ \not@ \ifgtest@ \gdef \thedots@ {\dotsb@ }\else \@xp \DOTS@ \meaning@ \DOTS@ \ifgtest@ \ifcase     number \DOTSCASE@ \gdef \thedots@ {\dotsb@ }\or \gdef \thedots@ {\dotsi }\else \fi \else \@xp \math@ \meaning@ \math@ \ifgtest@ \@xp \mathbin@ \meaning@ \mathbin@ \ifgtest@ \gdef \thedots@ {\dotsb@ }\else \@xp \mathrel@ \meaning@ \mathrel@ \ifgtest@ \gdef \thedots@ {\dotsb@ }\fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \thedots@ .
```

At this point, I give up....anyone care to continue this dissection?

Comment: The quick'n'easy answer is that it looks at the next token in the input stream and bases its decision on that. If it's something vertically raised such as a plus sign or an arrow, it uses `\cdots`, otherwise it uses `\ldots`.

Comment: Using `\show` is an extremely inefficient way to debug. Using `latexdef` is better (although I don't know if it was available 13 years ago), but it still loses the comments and line breaks in the source code, the best would be to download the source code and read it. In summary I believe it checks for a few common tokens (`,` or `\boldsymbol` or `\not`), then apply `\meaning` on the right-following token (assigned to `\meaning@` string), and check the string for `\mathchar` prefix, or initial strings `\DOTSC` etc. The commands `\DOTSC` themselves do nothing (assigned to `\relax`).