# Left-justified equations with left tags (so it looks like an enumeration)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align, labels

I want to make a math enivornment (preferably a customized align/flalign environment) with left-justified/left-aligned equations (as it is possible with the flalign environment) and left-aligned tags (instead of the default right alignment) but with the same indent handling flalign offers when using right-aligned equations with default right-aligned tags.

I've added a screenshot and a MWE for clarification.

I'd appreciate any help :-)

[image: Screenshot of MWE]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrbook}
\parindent0pt
\parskip6pt
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, enumitem, color}
\newcommand{\red}{\color{red}}
\newcommand{\set}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
\newcommand{\script}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
\renewcommand{\complement}{\mathcal{C}}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{lalign}{\tagsleft@true\flalign}{\endflalign}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\textbf{Definition} \quad ($\sigma$-field)
\begin{align}
& \Omega \in \script{A} \tag{SF1}\label{SF1} \\
& A \in \script{A} \Rightarrow \complement A \in \script{A} \tag{SF2}\label{SF2} \\
& A_1, A_2, \ldots \in \script{A} \Rightarrow \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \in \script{A} \tag{SF3}\label{SF3}
\end{align}

\textbf{Exercise} \quad Is $\script{A}$ a $\sigma$-field?
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
\item $\Omega$ arbitrary, $\script{A} = \set{\emptyset, \Omega}$.
\item $\ldots$
\end{enumerate}

\textbf{Solution} \quad

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
\item Let $\Omega$ be arbitrary and $\script{A} = \set{\emptyset, \Omega}$.

{\red It should be like this, but just the other way round:}
\begin{flalign}
&& \Omega \in \script{A} & \tag{\ref{SF1}} \\
&& \emptyset \in \script{A} \Rightarrow \complement \emptyset = \Omega \in \script{A} \tag{\ref{SF2}} \\
&& \Omega \in \script{A} \Rightarrow \complement \Omega = \emptyset \in \script{A} \notag \\
&& \emptyset, \Omega \in \script{A} \Rightarrow \emptyset \cup \Omega = \Omega \in \script{A} \tag{\ref{SF3}}
\end{flalign}
{\red This happens when I set \texttt{tagsleft@true} and use \texttt{flalign} for left-aligned equations:}
\begin{lalign}
& \Omega \in \script{A} & \tag{\ref{SF1}} \\
& \emptyset \in \script{A} \Rightarrow \complement \emptyset = \Omega \in \script{A} \tag{\ref{SF2}} \\
& \Omega \in \script{A} \Rightarrow \complement \Omega = \emptyset \in \script{A} \notag \\
& \emptyset, \Omega \in \script{A} \Rightarrow \emptyset \cup \Omega = \Omega \in \script{A} \tag{\ref{SF3}}
\end{lalign}
{\red I don't want centered equations because it should look like an enumeration:}
\begin{lalign}
& \Omega \in \script{A} \tag{\ref{SF1}} \\
& \emptyset \in \script{A} \Rightarrow \complement \emptyset = \Omega \in \script{A} \tag{\ref{SF2}} \\
& \Omega \in \script{A} \Rightarrow \complement \Omega = \emptyset \in \script{A} \notag \\
& \emptyset, \Omega \in \script{A} \Rightarrow \emptyset \cup \Omega = \Omega \in \script{A} \tag{\ref{SF3}}
\end{lalign}
{\red As it should look like (dirty coded, I want the code to be universally usable):}
\begin{lalign}
& \hspace*{1.2cm} \Omega \in \script{A} & \tag{\ref{SF1}} \\
& \hspace*{1.2cm} \emptyset \in \script{A} \Rightarrow \complement \emptyset = \Omega \in \script{A} \tag{\ref{SF2}} \\
& \hspace*{1.2cm} \Omega \in \script{A} \Rightarrow \complement \Omega = \emptyset \in \script{A} \notag \\
& \hspace*{1.2cm} \emptyset, \Omega \in \script{A} \Rightarrow \emptyset \cup \Omega = \Omega \in \script{A} \tag{\ref{SF3}}
\end{lalign}
\item $\ldots$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I'm afraid my question wasn't 100% clear. So here is a new MWE and screenshot referring to the answers which suggested using enumerations. The problem is: I don't want to make an enumeration which is independent from the defined equation labels. Each item shall get the name of the related equation label from \ref{...}. The equation labels must not be numerated. Here's the updated MWE:

[image: Updated MWE screenshot]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrbook}
\parindent0pt
\parskip6pt
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, enumitem, color}
\newcommand{\red}{\color{red}}
\newcommand{\set}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
\newcommand{\script}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
\renewcommand{\complement}{\mathcal{C}}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{lalign}{\tagsleft@true\flalign}{\endflalign}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\textbf{Definition} \quad ($\sigma$-field)
\begin{align}
& \Omega \in \script{A} \tag{SF1}\label{SF1} \\
& A \in \script{A} \Rightarrow \complement A \in \script{A} \tag{Complement}\label{SF2} \\
& A_1, A_2, \ldots \in \script{A} \Rightarrow \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \in \script{A} \tag{Union}\label{SF3}
\end{align}

\textbf{Exercise}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
\item Let $\Omega$ be arbitrary and $\script{A} = \set{\emptyset, \Omega}$.

{\red It should be like this, but just the other way round:}
\begin{flalign}
&& \Omega \in \script{A} & \tag{\ref{SF1}} \\
&& \emptyset \in \script{A} \Rightarrow \complement \emptyset = \Omega \in \script{A} \tag{\ref{SF2}} \\
&& \Omega \in \script{A} \Rightarrow \complement \Omega = \emptyset \in \script{A} \notag \\
&& \emptyset, \Omega \in \script{A} \Rightarrow \emptyset \cup \Omega = \Omega \in \script{A} \tag{\ref{SF3}}
\end{flalign}
{\red This happens when I set \texttt{tagsleft@true} and use \texttt{flalign} for left-aligned equations:}
\begin{lalign}
& \Omega \in \script{A} & \tag{\ref{SF1}} \\
& \emptyset \in \script{A} \Rightarrow \complement \emptyset = \Omega \in \script{A} \tag{\ref{SF2}} \\
& \Omega \in \script{A} \Rightarrow \complement \Omega = \emptyset \in \script{A} \notag \\
& \emptyset, \Omega \in \script{A} \Rightarrow \emptyset \cup \Omega = \Omega \in \script{A} \tag{\ref{SF3}}
\end{lalign}
{\red Enumerations aren't an option, because of this false indent handling:}
\begin{enumerate}
\item[(\ref{SF1})] Enumeration with custom item label.
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
\item[(\ref{SF2})] Enumeration with custom item label and \texttt{leftmargin=*}
\end{enumerate}
{\red It should be more like this (but it's not the way I want to code it all the time and it isn't 100\% accurate either:}
\begin{flalign*}
&\begin{array}{ll}
(\text{\ref{SF1}}) & \Omega \in \script{A} \\
(\text{\ref{SF2}}) & \emptyset \in \script{A} \Rightarrow \complement \emptyset = \Omega \in \script{A} \\
            & \Omega \in \script{A} \Rightarrow \complement \Omega = \emptyset \in \script{A} \\
(\text{\ref{SF3}}) & \emptyset, \Omega \in \script{A} \Rightarrow \emptyset \cup \Omega = \Omega \in \script{A}
\end{array}&
\end{flalign*}
\item $\ldots$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: how about a new list (using `enumitem` to help) and then just use inline math mode; you can use the `aligned` environment if you have more than one line of equations

Comment: I've already done this, but then I've also got indent problems. I'll update my original post regarding this issue.

Answer (score 2):

This *is* an enumeration:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,enumitem}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{definition}{Definition}

\newcommand{\set}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
\newcommand{\script}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
\renewcommand{\complement}{\mathcal{C}}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}[$\sigma$-field]\mbox{}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,label=(SF\arabic*)]
\item\label{SF1} $\Omega \in \script{A}$

\item\label{SF2} $A \in \script{A} \Rightarrow \complement A \in \script{A}$

\item\label{SF3} $A_1, A_2, \dotsc \in \script{A} \Rightarrow
  \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \in \script{A}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

I'd not use display style, in order not to spoil the vertical alignment. Note also `\dotsc` instead of `\ldots` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122497/4427). In order to go to a new line, just use `\mbox{}`.

[image]

With arbitrary labels:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,enumitem}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{definition}{Definition}

\newcommand{\script}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
\renewcommand{\complement}{\mathcal{C}}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{axioms}{+b}
 {
  \par
  \cs_set_eq:NN \axiom \__ternes_axioms_measure:nn
  #1
  \cs_set_eq:NN \axiom \__ternes_axioms_typeset:nn
  \begin{enumerate}[
    leftmargin=\dim_eval:n { \l__ternes_axioms_max_wd_dim + \labelsep},
    labelwidth=\l__ternes_axioms_max_wd_dim,
    itemindent=0pt,
  ]
  #1
  \end{enumerate}
 }{}

\dim_new:N \l__ternes_axioms_max_wd_dim
\dim_new:N \l__ternes_axioms_wd_dim

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__ternes_axioms_measure:nn
 {
  \settowidth{\l__ternes_axioms_wd_dim}{(#1)}
  \dim_set:Nn \l__ternes_axioms_max_wd_dim
   { \dim_max:nn { \l__ternes_axioms_max_wd_dim } { \l__ternes_axioms_wd_dim } }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__ternes_axioms_typeset:nn
 {
  \renewcommand{\theenumi}{#1}
  \item[(#1)]\refstepcounter{enumi} { \everymath{\displaystyle} #2 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}[$\sigma$-field]\mbox{}
\begin{axioms}
\axiom{SF1}{\label{SF1} $\Omega \in \script{A}$}

\axiom{Complement}{\label{SF2} $A \in \script{A} \Rightarrow \complement A \in \script{A}$}

\axiom{Union}{\label{SF3} $A_1, A_2, \dotsc \in \script{A} \Rightarrow
  \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \in \script{A}$}
\end{axioms}
\end{definition}

The second axiom is called~\ref{SF2}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But my problem aren't the equations within the definition but those equations referring the definition equations. Therefore I'm not able to use the enumeration and aligned environment trick. Imagine the equations aren't labeled as SF1, SF2, ... but rather like "Tree", "Apples", "Kangaroos". As I mentioned I want to refer those labels, not making a new independent enumeration. Also there don't have to be a numeration within the label (like SF1, SF2, ...).

Answer (score 2):

when the package `amsmath` is loaded, there is a check for `\iftagsleft@`
and quite a few settings are changed.  (this code takes up about 250 lines, and
is quite complex.)  if you apply `\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}` to your example,
the results are quite different, and probably more like what you are looking for.

by bypassing this extra code as you invoke `\iftagsleft@` by itself, after `amsmath`
has been totally digested, the calculations for setting the width of the display area
are never acted on properly.  you need to take that into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind about the indentation issues, and is just looking to use tag because of its ref workings, one can simply instead redefine `\theenumi` and `\labelenumi`.
In fact, you say you do mind about indentation, but it might help others (it's how I ended up here).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\nameditem[1]{
    \renewcommand{\theenumi}{#1}
    \renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\theenumi)}
    \item
    }
    
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\nameditem{SF1} $\Omega \in \mathcal{A}$\label{ax:SF1}
\nameditem{Complement} $A \in \mathcal{A} \Rightarrow \mathcal{C}(A) \in \mathcal{A}$
\nameditem{Union} $A_1, A_2, \dotsc \in \mathcal{A} \Rightarrow   \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \in \mathcal{A}$
\end{enumerate}

Ref: \ref{ax:SF1}

\end{document}
```

Which prints:

[image: 1]

There might be a better alternative than what I've done here, but I'm not sure what it is.