# Placement of ellipsis

Tags: punctuation, typography, ellipsis

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$(1-\theta_1) \dots (1-\theta_m)$
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Isn't the ellipsis supposed to be vertically centered since they indicate multiplication?

**Update**

I'm now fully convinced that I'm wrong. To everyone with access to *The TeXbook*, have a look at page 172. `:)`

Comment: Use `\cdots`. It works.

Comment: @Sigur I know, but what _should_ it be? Normally `\dots` places an ellipsis correct, so I'm wondering if I'm wong in my assumption or I've found an error. (I guess it's the first.)

Comment: What do you mean by *Normally \dots places an ellipsis correct*? Are you talking about other language?

Comment: @Sigur I'm not sure what you mean by your question. When I type `\dots` in a math expression in LaTeX, the ellipsis is almost always placed correct, so I think I might be wrong in assuming that the ellipsis in the example should be vertically centered. What is correct?

Comment: Related: [Difference of the `\dots*`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122491/5764)

Comment: `\dots` looks ahead to see what follows and based on that decides whether to use certain dots. The decision is based on whether the following element is `\mathbin`, or `\mathrel`, or ... And `(` does not provide `\mathrel` or `\mathbin` (the only two leading to `\dotsm` or`\dotsb` - a vertical adjustment of the dots).

Comment: @Werner Nice explanation. Thank you, Werner.

Comment: You should use `\dotsm` here.

Comment: @Werner it doesn't _just_ look at the math class of the following token, it uses  code such as `\def\rightdelim@{\gtest@true
 \ifx\@let@token)\else
 \ifx\@let@token]\else
 \ifx\@let@token\rbrack\else
 \ifx\@let@token\}\else`  to special case known delimiters and the entire `\DOTS?` mechanism so that it can be affected by the _preceding_ token. (not that it makes any difference in this case:-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the base LaTeX format `\dots` is just an alias for `\ldots` and is always on the baseline.

If you add `amsmath` then it does change according to context, but not in this case, it is more optimised for the case where the binary operator is explicit:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$(1-\theta_1) \times \dots \times(1-\theta_m)$
\end{document}
```

The dots will raise if you uncomment [`amsmath`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath).

Comment: +1. I've just learned that `amsmath` changes the vertical positioning based on the surrounding operators.

Comment: The problem comes when you don't use `\times`, but `\cdot`, for example, where you need to write `\cdots`.

Comment: @Manuel `amsmath` version of `\dots` gives centred dots if used with `\cdot`

Comment: No, I meant you have to omit the `\cdot`, ergo you have to explicitly write `\cdots`.

Comment: @Manuel Oh I see OK

Answer (score 16):

Only for the best practitioners. We should stick to the semantic rules by using the following dots.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \verb+\dotsc+ for comma separated element $A_1, A_2, \dotsc, A_{n-1}, A_n$.
    \item \verb+\dotsb+ for binary operator $A_1 +A_2 + \dotsb + A_{n-1} + A_n$.
    \item \verb+\dotsm+ for multiplication $A_1 A_2 \dotsm A_{n-1}  A_n$.
    \item \verb+\dotsi+ for integral  $\int_{A_1} \int_{A_2} \dotsi \int_{A_{n-1}}  \int_{A_n}$.
    \item \verb+\dotso+ for others.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Advantages:

You can redefine the implementation for each dots above in the preamble whenever your institution ask you to change its behavior to meet its own adopted layout. If you use just `\ldots` and `\cdots` rather than the above semantic dots then you have to manually change them per equation --- as a result, this job makes your life boring.

### `\dots` (general dots)  versus `\dots*` (amsmath's semantically defined dots)

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
        \item (\verb+\dots+)  $A_1, \dots, A_n$ \textcolor{red}{v.s.}\ $A_1, \dotsc, A_n$  (\verb+\dotsc+).
    \item (\verb+\dots+)  $A_1 + \dots + A_n$ \textcolor{red}{v.s.}\ $A_1 + \dotsb + A_n$ (\verb+\dotsb+).
    \item (\verb+\dots+)  $A_1 \dots  A_n$ \textcolor{red}{v.s.}\ $A_1 \dotsm  A_n$ (\verb+\dotsm+).
    \item (\verb+\dots+) $\int_{A_1} \dots  \int_{A_n}$ \textcolor{red}{v.s.}\ $\int_{A_1} \dotsi  \int_{A_n}$ (\verb+\dotsi+).
    \item (\verb+\dots+) \dots\ \textcolor{red}{v.s.}\ \dotso\ (\verb+\dotso+).
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I know of the "Short Math Guide for LaTeX" but thank you none the less. `:)`

Comment: I don't agree. You should use `\dots` except when it can't determine the semantics (at end of lists, for instance) or it gets it wrong.

Comment: @egreg: I don't understand what you said. Probably because you also did not understand what I meant. :-)

Comment: You meant wrong; it's by redefining `\dots` that the classes can use their preferred placement (low or center) depending on the semantics.

Comment: @egreg: I still don't understand. What I said is that when the institutions want us to change the meaning of `\dotsc` to be centered rather than bottom aligned or `\dotsm` to be bottom aligned rather than centered, we can do the requirement without hassle by just redefining `\dotsc` and `\dotsc` at the preamble without having to change each equation. This approach is only possible when we use `\dotsc` for comma separated elements and `\dotsm` for multiplication as explained above. If we don't use `\dotsc` and/or `\dotsm` then redefining `\dots` will not be possible.

Comment: Redefining `\dots` is not possible as `\dots` are used everywhere with different semantic meaning in equations. If we redefine `\dots` to be centered then all `\dots` becomes centered, for example --- it might not be what we want to achieve.

Comment: @DonutE.Knot No, that's not how it works. I said “redefine `\dots`” to mean ”redefine the working of the inner macros called by `\dots` to take care of what surrounds it”. The idea is that the user only uses `\dots` except when at the end of a list.

Comment: @egreg: My argumentation above is based on my understanding after reading `amsmath`'s documentation on page 11-12. I don't know whether or not the documentation is also wrong.

Comment: @DonutE.Knot It may be not clear, but if you look at the examples, they are only for final dots. There would be no need for adding the internal macro `\DOTS` in several commands to take care of transforming `\dots` into the right call, if one those five commands was requested in all cases.

Comment: @DonutE.Knot http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122497/4427