# How to indent equations?

Tags: equations

I have 2 equations which looks like:

A = B+ C + D... , While x is true.

The problem is, the equation is quite big which goes on for 2 lines. How do I give an indent to the second line so it looks like:

```
A = B + C + D + E + F +
    G + H + I + ... , while x is true.
```

Comment: You can use the `align` or `array` environment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `align` environment if you want. Remove the `*` to get the numbered equation form. The following is MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
A {}={} & B + C + D + E + F +\\
        & G + H + I + \dotsb, \quad \text{while $x$ is true.}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Another flavor would be like:

```
\[
\begin{aligned}
A {}={} & B + C + D + E + F +\\
        & G + H + I + \dotsb, \quad \text{while $x$ is true.}
\end{aligned}
\]
```

or

```
\[
\begin{array}{r@{}c@{}l}
A   &{}={}& B + C + D + E + F +\\
    &     & G + H + I + \dotsb, \quad \text{while $x$ is true.}
\end{array}
\]
```

This does not give any numbered version but keeps the alignment. I recommend you read the `amsmath` documentation and other math related sources to get acquainted with alignments in equations. For example, here in TeX.SX you can make a quick search and you will see several examples of alignment. For instance if I search `alignment in equations` I would get lots of examples. ([click me](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=alignment%20in%20equations))

I will also invite you to read the following links:

1. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147149/10898
2. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122497/10898

Comment: If you remove the `*` you get two numbered equations.

Comment: @karlkoeller Oops guess am still sleepy......

Comment: Thank you. Your first example worked. I do not have a lot of equations, just a few here and there.

Comment: @ctrl-shift-esc glad to have helped. happy texing

Answer (score 10):

Try something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
  A ={} & B + C + D + E + F + \\
        & G + H + I + \dots, \quad\text{while $x$ is true}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

If you don't want the equation to be numbered use `equation*` instead of `equation`.

As Svend suggested in the comment, in this case it is probably better using `\dotsb` instead of `\dots`.

[image]

Comment: `\dots` --> `\dotsb`.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Yes, in this case it is probably the best choice.

Answer (score 2):

You also may use the `multlined` environment if you load the `mathtools` package (don't load `amsmath` in that case, it does it for you) ; this code lets you shift the second equation with respect to the first one, instead of aligning them

```
\begin{equation}  
  \begin{multlined}  
   A = B + C + D + E + F + \\\  
   G + H + I + \dots,\qquad \text{\rlap{while $x$ is true. }}  
  \end{multlined} 
\end{equation}
```

Here is the result:[image]

Comment: By the way, how does one incorporate a nice-looking output? I converted my pdf to a png, but the result displays poorly.

Answer (score 1):

Just for comparing [Karlkoeller's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147571/19356) that used `split` with mine that uses `aligned`.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[a5paper,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\hrulefill
\begin{equation}  
\begin{split}
A = {} 
& B + C + D + \\
& E + F + \\
& G + H + I + \dots, \quad\text{using split}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\hrulefill
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\hrulefill
\begin{equation}  
A = 
\!
\begin{aligned}[t]
& B + C + D + \\
& E + F + \\
& G + H + I + \dots, \quad\text{using aligned}.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\hrulefill
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I suggest making the following adjustment ``& E + F +{} \\`` to fine tune the alignment.

Comment: @azetina: That is correct. I will edit later.