# How to indent a particular equation

Tags: indentation

I set the global setting  as \setlength\mathindent{0pt} ,but I want to indent a particular equation.
How to do so?

Comment: Please, can you put an example for your question, if possible? Thank you very much. Does question help you? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147570/how-to-indent-equations

Answer (score 2):

A comment up front: I will assume that you've set `\setlength\mathindent{0pt}`, *not* `\setlength\mathindent[0pt]`. I will also assume that you've set the option `fleqn` either at the document class level or while loading the `amsmath` package.

Equation-specific indentation from the left can be achieved by inserting spacing commands such as `\quad` and `\qquad` or, if you need really fine control, either `\mkern` ("math kern"; this commands takes lengths in multiples of `mu`, where `18mu=1em`) or `\hspace`, `\hskip`, and other horizontal-spacing commands.

[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength\mathindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
&1+1=2\\
&\mkern18mu 1+1=2\\
&\quad 1+1=2\\        % width of \quad=1em=18mu
&\mkern72mu 1+1=2\\
&\qquad\qquad 1+1=2\\ % width of \qquad=2em=36mu
&\hskip3cm 1+1=2\\
&\hspace*{3cm} 1+1=2
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: your assumption are correct, but I was looking for some command that would just arrange the equation normally in the centre and ignore the setlength effect for the particular case.

Comment: @Hawkingo - Your write-up noted that you wanted to "indent a particular equation"; nothing about *centering* it on a line. In view of the fact that my answer is evidently of no use to you, would you like me to delete it? Please advise.

Comment: It's upto you. others might get help from your answer, if it's not me.