# Writing a equation with many regions

Tags: math-mode

How to write a equation like the following which contain many regions?
[image: GHASH]

Comment: Use `cases` environment.

Comment: Suggested `cases` is a good choice. You can also use `array`, if for some reason you don't want to use `amsmath`. But I can see some additional traps. In particular, what are `len` and `||`? Their behaviour should depend on their function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `cases` environment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}\begin{equation}
f(n) = \begin{cases} n/2 &\mbox{if } n \equiv 0 \\
(3n +1)/2 & \mbox{if } n \equiv 1 \\
(3n +1)/2 & \mbox{if } n \equiv 1 
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Better `\text{…}` than `\mbox{…}`. And if you load `mathtools` insteado of `amsmath`, you can use `cases*` environment, which sets the second column to text mode.

Answer (score 3):

Here is MWE that can help you to begin:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[  X_i=
    \begin{cases}
    0                           & \text{ for } i=0\\
    (X_{i-1}\oplus A_i)\cdot H  & \text{ for } i=1,\dotsc,m-1
    \end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Also read the following:

1. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122497/10898