# Parenthetical Errors

Tags: math-mode

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

8.) Now calculate the logarithm of the $n$th term in the sequence, i.e. log($a_{n}$). \indent Use the series representation of the logarithm
\\
\\ \indent \indent log(1 + $x$) = - $   \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}$ $ \frac {(-1)^{k}}{k} x^{k} $, 
\\
\\ \indent \indent to simplify the answer. What do you conclude?
\\ 
\\ \indent \indent log((1 + $\frac{1}{n})^{n}}$) 
\\ 
\\ \indent \indent \indent \indent  = n $\cdot$ log(1 + $\frac{1}{n}$) 
\\
\\ \indent \indent \indent \indent = n $\cdot$ ( - $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}$ $ \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k} (\frac{1}{n})^{k}$) 
\\
\\ \indent \indent \indent \indent = -n $\cdot$ ($ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}$ $  \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k} (\frac{1}{n}^{k}})$
\\
\\ \indent \indent \indent \indent = -n [ $\{$$ \frac{(-1)^{1}}{1} \cdot \frac{1}{n^{1}}$$\}$$_{n=1} $ + {$ \frac{(-1)^{2}}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{n^{2}}$\}_{n=1} + \{$\frac{(-1)^{3}}{3}$ $\cdot$ $\frac {1}{n^{3}}$\}$_{n=1}$ + \indent \indent \indent \indent ...]
\\
\\ \indent \indent \indent \indent = -n $ \cdot$ [\{- $\frac{1}{n}$\}_{n=1} + \{ $\frac{1}{2n^{2}}$\} _{n=1} + \{$\frac{(-1)} {3n^{3}}$\}_{n=1} + ... \: ]
\\ 
\\ \indent \indent \indent \indent = - n $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k} \frac{1}{n}^{k}$
\\
\\ \indent \indent \indent \indent = -$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k} \frac{1}{n}^{k-1}$ 
\\
\\ \indent \indent \indent \indent = -[\{$\frac{(-1)}{1} \cdot \frac{1}{1}$\}_{n=1} + \{ $\frac{(-1)^{2}} {2}$ $\cdot$ $\frac{1}{n}$\}_{n=1} + \{ $\frac{(-1}^{3}}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{n^{2}}$ \}_{n=1} + ... ]
\\
\\ \indent \indent \indent \indent -[\{-1\}_{n=1} + \{ $\frac{1}{2n}$ $\}$_{n=1} + \{ $\frac{-1}{3n^2}}$ \}_{n=1} + ... ]
```

Comment: If you see a document with `\\ ` not in a tabular or a document using `\indent` it's usually a sign that something is wrong.....

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! But do you have a question? The code fragment is posted but it isn't a complete document ending with `\end{document}` so we can't run it, and you haven't said what you want it to do.

Answer (score 4):

You should use the `align` environment from the `amsmath` package:

[image]

There were *numerous* problems with this. Here are a few them (not sure I got them all):

- Do not attempt to align that many things manually. A few tweaks are sometime necessary but the `align` environment does most of the work for you.
- Instead of `...` I used `dots` as per [Difference of the \dots*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122491/difference-of-the-dots)
- I used `\intertext` to insert textual content within the `align` environment.
- For resizing brackets, I used the fixed size of `\Big`, but you can also use the `\left`/`\right` construct. Although the manually sized braces are usually better.
- Removed outer parenthesis on the line beginning with `-n` as they are not needed.

### Notes:

- Also, I may have messed up your math, so please do double check.
- An excellent reference for math mode is Herbert Voss'  [comprehensive review of mathematics in (La)TeX](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/math/voss/mathmode/).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

8.) Now calculate the logarithm of the $n$th term in the sequence, i.e. $\log(a_{n})$. 

Use the series representation of the logarithm

\begin{align*}
\log(1 + x) &= -    \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^{k}}{k} x^{k}, \\
\intertext{To simplify the answer. What do you conclude?}
\log((1 + \frac{1}{n})^{n}) 
    &=  n \cdot \log(1 + \frac{1}{n}) \\
    &=  n \cdot \Big( -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}  \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k} \Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big)^{k}  \Big) \\
    &= -n \cdot   \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}  \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k} \Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big)^{k}  \\
    &= -n \Big[ \Big\{ \frac{(-1)^{1}}{1} \cdot \frac{1}{n^{1}} \Big\}_{n=1}  + \Big\{ \frac{(-1)^{2}}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{n^{2}} \Big\}_{n=1} + 
            \Big\{\frac{(-1)^{3}}{3} \cdot \frac {1}{n^{3}} \Big\}_{n=1} +  \dotsb \Big] \\
    &= -n  \cdot \Big[ \Big\{- \frac{1}{n} \Big\}_{n=1} + \Big\{ \frac{1}{2n^{2}} \Big\} _{n=1} + \Big\{ \frac{(-1)} {3n^{3}} \Big\}_{n=1} + \dotsb \: \Big] \\
    &= - n \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k} \frac{1}{n}^{k} \\
    &= -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k} \frac{1}{n}^{k-1} \\
    &= -\Big[ \Big\{\frac{(-1)}{1} \cdot \frac{1}{1} \Big\}_{n=1} + \Big\{ \frac{(-1)^{2}} {2} \cdot \frac{1}{n} \Big\}_{n=1} + \Big\{ \frac{(-1)^{3}}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{n^{2}} \Big\}_{n=1} + \dotsb \Big] \\
    &-\Big[ \{-1\}_{n=1} + \Big\{ \frac{1}{2n} \Big\}_{n=1} + \Big\{ \frac{-1}{3n^2} \Big\}_{n=1} + \dotsb \Big]
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 You are a far faster typer than I… As a complement to this answer (mine uses a couple macros to ease understanding), OP should take a look at https://gist.github.com/vermiculus/9946499.

Comment: @SeanAllred: Do you want to post an answer? I can delete mine...

Comment: Not to worry! I was going to post only a half-answer at any rate; I still haven't finished.  Don't worry about it `:)` [*I should stop procrastinating on my thesis at any rate…*]

Comment: @SeanAllred :-) Yeah, I should get back to my _real_ work as well.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the question is and the code does not compile. Let us start at line 4, the first mistake.

`log((1 + $\frac{1}{n})^{n}}$)` returns a mistake because the first closing parenthesis is in math mode, whereas the corresponding opening parenthesis is not.
You also have a closing `}` that corresponds to no opening `{`.

Try `$\log((1 + \frac{1}{n})^{n})$`. Notice that the full mathematical expression should be in math mode. `\log` gives a better display of the log function.

This should give you some ideas for the rest of the document. There are many mistakes you should be able of handling.