# Fit inside enumerate

Tags: enumerate, fit

[image]

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item $\mathcal{D}(m)=0$ for $m\in\mathbb{Z}$,

  \item $\mathcal{D}(x^{-1})=-x^{-1}\sigma(x^{1})\mathcal{D}(x)$,

  \item $\mathcal{D}(x^{n})=\left( {\sigma ({x^{n - 1}}) + \sigma ({x^{n - 2}})x + ... + \sigma (x){x^{n - 2}} + {x^{n - 1}}} \right)\mathcal{D}(x)$,

  \item $\mathcal{D}(x^{-n})=- \left( {\sigma ({x^-n}){x^-1} + \sigma ({x^{-(n - 1)}}){x^-2} + ... + \sigma ({x^-2}){x^{-(n - 1)}} + \sigma ({x^-1}){x^-n}} \right)\mathcal{D}(x)$ for $n\geq1$.
\end{enumerate}
```

How can I fit the last equation in article'paper size?

Comment: Could you please make it a fully compilable example? It is helping solvers a lot to actually start experimenting with the code!

Comment: One option is to use the `\sum` notation:   `\item $\mathcal{D}(x^{-n})= -\mathcal{D}(x)\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sigma ({x^{-n+i-1}}){x^{i}}$, for $n\geq1$.`

Comment: LaTeX won't break the equation, since the breaking point doesn't lie with an operator. You may have to rewrite the equation (perhaps using a different notation) or manually break it.

Comment: Thank u for advice Gonzalo Medina but it was thougt. My post is only a sample for this porblem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be to use the inner `aligned` environment and make the equation over several lines:

[image]

### Notes:

- Use `x^{-1}` instead of `x^-1`.
- Use `\dotsb` instead of `...` as per [Difference of the \dots*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122491/difference-of-the-dots).
- [The `showframe` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe)
  was used just to show the page margins.
  It is not needed in you actual use case.

---

You could also consider aligning the left hand side of the equations.  The MWE below produces a `r`ight alignment:

[image]

But by replacing the `[r]` with a `[l]` in the `\MakeBox` you get:

[image]

I think I prefer the `[r]` aligned version.

---

### Code: `aligned`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item $\mathcal{D}(m)=0$ for $m\in\mathbb{Z}$,
  
  \item $\mathcal{D}(x^{-1})=-x^{-1}\sigma(x^{1})\mathcal{D}(x)$,

  \item $\mathcal{D}(x^{n})=\left( {\sigma ({x^{n - 1}}) + \sigma ({x^{n - 2}})x + ... + \sigma (x){x^{n - 2}} + {x^{n - 1}}} \right)\mathcal{D}(x)$,

  \item $\begin{aligned}[t]\mathcal{D}(x^{-n}) 
          &=- \Big( \sigma ({x^-n}){x^{-1}} + \sigma ({x^{-(n - 1)}}){x^-2} + \dotsb \\
          &\qquad+ \sigma ({x^-2}){x^{-(n - 1)}} + \sigma ({x^{-1}}){x^-n} \Big)\mathcal{D}(x)
           \text{ for } n\geq1.
          \end{aligned}$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

---

### Code: `aligned` with `\MakeBox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand*{\MakeBox}[1]{\makebox[\widthof{$\mathcal{D}(x^{-n})$}][r]{$#1$}}%

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item $\MakeBox{\mathcal{D}(m)}=0$ for $m\in\mathbb{Z}$,

  \item $\MakeBox{\mathcal{D}(x^{-1})}=-x^{-1}\sigma(x^{1})\mathcal{D}(x)$,

  \item $\MakeBox{\mathcal{D}(x^{n})}=\left( {\sigma ({x^{n - 1}}) + \sigma ({x^{n - 2}})x + ... + \sigma (x){x^{n - 2}} + {x^{n - 1}}} \right)\mathcal{D}(x)$,

  \item $\begin{aligned}[t]\mathcal{D}(x^{-n}) 
          &=- \Big( \sigma ({x^-n}){x^{-1}} + \sigma ({x^{-(n - 1)}}){x^-2} + \dotsb \\
          &\qquad+ \sigma ({x^-2}){x^{-(n - 1)}} + \sigma ({x^{-1}}){x^-n} \Big)\mathcal{D}(x)
           \text{ for } n\geq1.
          \end{aligned}$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```