# Dots in a system of constraints

Tags: align

I would like to write a linear program as follows:

[image]

The text above and below is shown only to indicate the position of the system on the page.

I wrote

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
& \text{max (o min)} & c_1 x_1 &+ \dots + c_n x_n \\
& \text{soggetto a} & a_{11} x_1 &+ \dots + a_{1n} x_n \sim b_1 \\
&& a_{m1} x_1 &+ \dots + a_{mn} x_n \sim b_m,
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

but I hadn't the same result. In particular to the space between words and system, and I do not know how to insert the dots vertical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\vdots` for the vertical dots, and I'd recommend using an `alignat` to achieve the desired result:

[image]

You can also get the variables right aligned with a bit more work:

[image]

### Notes:

- I also replaced the `\dots` with `\dotsb`.  See [Difference of the \dots*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122491/difference-of-the-dots/) for more details.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{5}
& \text{max (o min) } &c_1 x_1     &{}+ \dotsb &&{}+ c_n x_n \\
& \text{soggetto a }  &a_{11} x_1  &{}+ \dotsb &&{}+ a_{1n} x_n &&{}\sim b_1 \\\nonumber
&                                  &    \vdots \\
&                     & a_{m1} x_1 &{}+ \dots &&{}+ a_{mn} x_n &&{}\sim b_m
\end{alignat}
If you want the variables right aligned:
\begin{alignat}{6}
& \text{max (o min) } &c_1 x_1     &&{}+ \dotsb &&{}+{} &&c_n x_n \\
& \text{soggetto a }  &a_{11} x_1  &&{}+ \dotsb &&{}+{} &&a_{1n} x_n &{}\sim b_1 \\\nonumber
&                                  &&    \vdots \\
&                     & a_{m1} x_1 &&{}+ \dotsb &&{}+{} &&a_{mn} x_n &{}\sim b_m
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\dotsb` behaves like a binary operator: if nothing follows it, no space is added. Thus, the `+ \dotsb &` in the second example should be `+ \dotsb {}&`

Comment: And to obtain also "tilda" (~) aligned?

Comment: there is more space before the second plus than after the first one.  this can be fixed by removing the `{}` before the second plus, since `\dotsb` already takes care of it.

Comment: @Pippothedog: Have updated solution to align the `~` as well.