# tab is not working in latex

Tags: spacing

I am new in the world of latex . At this time , now I am writing thesis . I want to have tabs in tex document . For this purpose , I have written the following code .

```
\hspace{2cm}$ \mathbf{a_{11}x_1 + a_{12}x_2 +. . . + a_{1n}x_n = b_1 } $ \newline
                    \hspace{2cm}$\mathbf{a_{21}x_1 + a_{22}x_2 +. . . + a_{2n}x_n = b_2 }$\newline
                    \hspace{2cm} ...     ...     ...   ...    ...  ... \newline
                    \medskip ...     ...     ...   ...    ...  ...\newline
                    \medskip ...     ...     ...   ...    ...  ...\newline
                    \medskip $\mathbf{a_{n1}x_1 + a_{n2}x_2 +. . . + a_{nn}x_n = b_n }   $ \newline
```

But this code generates tab in first line and then in the next line the tabs is not generated . Why ?  Please help .

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\hspace*{}` to get the desired effect:

[image]

However you really should use some sort of math environment such as `align`:

[image]

### Notes:

- Instead of `...` you should use `\dotsb`. See [Difference of the \dots*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122491/difference-of-the-dots) for more details.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\hspace{2cm}$ \mathbf{a_{11}x_1 + a_{12}x_2 +. . . + a_{1n}x_n = b_1 } $ \newline
                    \hspace*{2cm}$\mathbf{a_{21}x_1 + a_{22}x_2 +. . . + a_{2n}x_n = b_2 }$\newline
                    \hspace*{2cm} ...     ...     ...   ...    ...  ... \newline
                    \medskip\hspace*{2cm} ...     ...     ...   ...    ...  ...\newline
                    \medskip\hspace*{2cm} ...     ...     ...   ...    ...  ...\newline
                    \medskip\hspace*{2cm} $\mathbf{a_{n1}x_1 + a_{n2}x_2 +. . . + a_{nn}x_n = b_n }   $ \newline 
                    
But instead you should use
\begin{align*}
    a_{11}x_1 + a_{12}x_2 + \dotsb + a_{1n}x_n &= b_1 \\
    a_{21}x_1 + a_{22}x_2 + \dotsb + a_{2n}x_n &= b_2  \\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using  `array` and `flalign` allows for a better-looking long series of dots with the `\hdotsfor` command. In this context, a plain `\dots` will do the same job as \dotsb:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\begin{document}
\noindent Another solution: \useshortskip

\begin{flalign*}
 \hspace{2cm} &
\begin{array}{@{}r@{} >{{}}l} \\
 a_{11}x_1 + a_{12}x_2 + \dots + a_{1n}x_n &{} = b_1\\
 a_{21}x_1 + a_{22}x_2 + \dots + a_{2n}x_n &= b_2 \\
\hdotsfor{2}
\end{array} &
\end{flalign*}

Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.
\end{document}
```

[image]