# \dotsc or \dots in this case?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I know that we should use `\dotsc` with a comma and `\dots` if there is no comma. 
But what if I have a comma on the right side and no comma on the left side, for example in

```
Pr[X_i | X_{i+1}, ... ]
```

Which one should I use?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `\dotsX` commands are just for the cases where it would be impossible to determine what kind of dots are expected, because they're at the end rather than in the middle of a list. So here `\dotsc` is the right command. You should probably use `\mid` instead of `|`.

Comment: You can have a look at [Difference of the \dots*](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122491/)

Comment: thanks for the link.
By the way, I know it doesn't fit here, but because you told me to use `\mid`. 
Is there something like `\left`, `\right` to make `\mid` adapt its size?

Comment: by the way: If it is marked as duplicate, should I delete this question?

Comment: You can use `\bigm|`, `\Bigm|`, `\biggm|` or `\Biggm|` for a bigger bar; there are other questions dealing with this problem. Don't worry about the duplicate question; feel free to ask, closing as duplicate is just a way to keep information tighter.

Comment: @user136457 - You could try `\left[x]`, `\middle[y]`, and `\right[z]`, where `[x]`, `[y]`, and `[z]` could be `\{`, `\,|\,`, and `\}`, respectively.