# Which dots-type in math?

Tags: math-mode

I am using the vim latex suite and when I type `...` it automatically changes them into `\ldots` if it is text or `\cdots` if I am in a math environment. So I thought that `\cdots` is the "right" thing to use in math.

But I just now saw that using `\cdots` it looks very odd with something like this:

```
$b_{1}, b_{2}, \cdots, b_{n}$
```

In the document it looks simliar to this formatting: `b1,b2,... ,bn`
After the dots and before the comma there is a whitespace. If I use `\dots` there is no space at all between them.

What would be the right way to do dots? Should I just stay with `\cdots` but which lookes a little bit strange? Should I use `\cdots` and add spaceing by myself where I need it?

Comment: I think I have found the answer in another question (sorry for that, I didn't find it altough I was searching before I asked mine). The answer is here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122491/difference-of-the-dots (Should I marke my own answer as the correct answer?)