# Multiple multiplication dots in a row

Tags: symbols

What would be a correct way to write this (or is there another correct way)? 
Thank you!!

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}

    \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}


    \begin{document}
    \begin{gather*}
        x_1\cdot x_2 \cdot \dotsm \cdot x_n \\
        x_1\cdot x_2 \cdot \dotsc \cdot x_n \\
        x_1\cdot x_2 \cdot\, \dotsm \,\cdot x_n
    \end{gather*}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would think none of the above, but `x_1\cdot x_2 \dotsm x_n`, but that is just me.  Welcome to the site.

Comment: Just use `\dots` and `amsmath` will choose the right form.

Comment: This may off topic, but why not use `\prod_{i = 1}^{n} x_{i}`?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122491/difference-of-the-dots

Answer (score 9):

From the "The Chicago Manual of Style", 16th edition, paragraph 12.20:

> If the multiplication dot is present, then ellipsis points should be on the baseline and not centered.
>
> [image: Result]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$a_1\cdot a_2 \cdot\ldots\cdot a_n$\quad not\quad
$a_1\cdot a_2 \cdot\dots\cdot a_n$
\end{document}
```