# \cdots and \dots, which one to use?

Tags: math-mode

Sometimes I just don't know which one to use, `\cdots` or `\dots`? This question is more like using the correct math style instead of technical details of LaTeX, but I hope someone can help.

Comment: For maths,  I use `\dots`, and `amsmath` is smart enough to know which king of dots it has to use For text, I have the unicode character `…` on my keyboard.

Comment: "king" or "kind" ?  :-)

Comment: Related: [Difference of the `\dots*`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122491/)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you have to decide, decide between `\ldots` and `\cdots` which are the latex commands for low and centred dots, `\dots` is an `amsmath` command that tries to automatically make the choice for you and automatically switches between `\ldots` and `\cdots` depending on the following symbol.

As a general rule, use `\cdots` if the following thing is centered on the math axis, such as `+` or `\rightarrow`, and `\ldots` if it is punctuation such as `.` or `,`

Answer (score 7):

The best practices for dots, in my opinion, are those mentioned in *[The Art of LaTeX](http://static.latexstudio.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/The+art+of+latex.pdf)* by Helin Gai. See page 69 of that document.

Note: I am not Helin Gai. :)