# Multiple alignment in math mode without much space

Tags: math-mode, equations, align

There are several post on multiple alignments, but I cant find a solution regarding my problem.

```
%%%%% Dokumentenklasse mit verschiedenen Attributen
\documentclass[a4paper, abstracton, bibtotocnumbered,liststotoc,12pt]{scrartcl}

%%%%% Betriebssystemabhängige Eingabedekodierung
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} %% für Windows
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\matr}[1]{\mathbf{#1}} 
\newcommand{\X}{\matr{X}} %Matrix von X
\newcommand{\y}{\matr{y}} %y als voller Vektor
\newcommand{\Xt}{\X^\mathbf{T}} %Matrix von X
\newcommand{\x}{\matr{x}}%Regressor von X
\newcommand{\xt}{\x^\mathbf{T}}%Regressor von X
\newcommand{\betahat}{\hat{\beta}} %betahat


\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
\Xt\y-\Xt\X\betahat &= \lambda s\\
\Leftrightarrow \underbrace{\Xt \y}_{p \times 1} &= \underbrace{\vphantom{ \Xt \y } \lambda s}_{p \times 1}, \quad s \in [-1,1]^{p} \\
\intertext{\textnormal{Das $j$-te Element entspricht}}
\xt_{j}\y &= \lambda s_j, \quad \quad s_j \in [-1,1] \Leftrightarrow \lambda s_j \in [-\lambda, \lambda] \\
\Leftrightarrow  |\xt_{j}\y| &\leq \lambda, \quad \forall j \in \{1,...,p\}
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

I am using the following code and I want to multiple align the staments that are following after the comma and `\quad`. I tried to multilpe align them with `&&` but the space between the equations and the other arguments will be far too large. I roughly want the same space as produced by quad but with an alignment of the arguments.

Comment: If you look at published mathematical literature (books and papers) you will find that almost no one uses equivalence arrows (`\Leftrightarrow`) at the beginning of each line. Whether that is because people think it is a bad idea in general or whether they just can't get it done sensibly in LaTeX is probably open for interpretation.

Comment: That said, maybe `alignat` is for you: `\begin{alignat*}{2}
\Xt\y-\Xt\X\betahat &= \lambda s\\
\Leftrightarrow \underbrace{\Xt \y}_{p \times 1} &= \underbrace{\vphantom{ \Xt \y } \lambda s}_{p \times 1}, &&\quad s \in [-1,1]^{p} \\
\intertext{\textnormal{Das $j$-te Element entspricht}}
\xt_{j}\y &= \lambda s_j, &&\quad s_j \in [-1,1] \Leftrightarrow \lambda s_j \in [-\lambda, \lambda] \\
\Leftrightarrow  |\xt_{j}\y| &\leq \lambda, &&\quad \forall j \in \{1,...,p\}
\end{alignat*}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For multiple alignment points you can use `alignat`:

> [image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, abstracton, bibtotocnumbered,liststotoc,12pt]{scrartcl}

%%%%% Betriebssystemabhängige Eingabedekodierung
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} %% für Windows
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\matr}[1]{\mathbf{#1}} 
\newcommand{\X}{\matr{X}} %Matrix von X
\newcommand{\y}{\matr{y}} %y als voller Vektor
\newcommand{\Xt}{\X^\mathbf{T}} %Matrix von X
\newcommand{\x}{\matr{x}}%Regressor von X
\newcommand{\xt}{\x^\mathbf{T}}%Regressor von X
\newcommand{\betahat}{\hat{\beta}} %betahat

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
  \Xt\y-\Xt\X\betahat & = \lambda s\\
  \Leftrightarrow \underbrace{\Xt \y}_{p \times 1} & = \underbrace{\vphantom{ \Xt \y } \lambda s}_{p \times 1}, & \quad & s \in [-1,1]^{p} \\
  \intertext{\textnormal{Das $j$-te Element entspricht}}
  \xt_{j}\y &= \lambda s_j, & \quad & s_j \in [-1,1] \Leftrightarrow \lambda s_j \in [-\lambda, \lambda] \\
  \Leftrightarrow |\xt_{j}\y| &\leq \lambda, & \quad & \forall j \in \{1,\dots,p\}
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ummm, you were 30 sec faster ...

Comment: @AboAmmar It happens ;)

Answer (score 7):

The `flalign` environment’s name means *full length align*, which means that the whole line width will be used when there is more than one alignment point.

In order to control the alignment you can use `alignat` or just `align` if you don't want to bother.

```
%%%%% Dokumentenklasse mit verschiedenen Attributen
\documentclass[a4paper, abstracton,12pt]{scrartcl}

%%%%% Betriebssystemabhängige Eingabedekodierung
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} %% für Windows
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\matr}[1]{\mathbf{#1}} 
\newcommand{\X}{\matr{X}} %Matrix von X
\newcommand{\y}{\matr{y}} %y als voller Vektor
\newcommand{\Xt}{\X^\mathbf{T}} %Matrix von X
\newcommand{\x}{\matr{x}}%Regressor von X
\newcommand{\xt}{\x^\mathbf{T}}%Regressor von X
\newcommand{\betahat}{\hat{\beta}} %betahat


\begin{document}

\section{\texttt{alignat}}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\Xt\y-\Xt\X\betahat
  &= \lambda s\\
\Leftrightarrow {\underbrace{\Xt \y}_{p \times 1}}
  &= {\underbrace{\vphantom{ \Xt \y } \lambda s}_{p \times 1}}, 
  &\quad& s \in [-1,1]^{p} \\
\intertext{Das $j$-te Element entspricht}
\xt_{j}\y
  &= \lambda s_j,
  &\quad& s_j \in [-1,1] \Leftrightarrow \lambda s_j \in [-\lambda, \lambda] \\
\Leftrightarrow  |\xt_{j}\y|
  &\leq \lambda,
  &\quad& \forall j \in \{1,\dots,p\}
\end{alignat*}

\section{\texttt{align}}
\begin{align*}
\Xt\y-\Xt\X\betahat
  &= \lambda s\\
\Leftrightarrow {\underbrace{\Xt \y}_{p \times 1}}
  &= {\underbrace{\vphantom{ \Xt \y } \lambda s}_{p \times 1}}, 
  && s \in [-1,1]^{p} \\
\intertext{Das $j$-te Element entspricht}
\xt_{j}\y
  &= \lambda s_j,
  && s_j \in [-1,1] \Leftrightarrow \lambda s_j \in [-\lambda, \lambda] \\
\Leftrightarrow  |\xt_{j}\y|
  &\leq \lambda,
  && \forall j \in \{1,\dots,p\}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A few points to note.

1. `latin1` is *not* “for Windows”. Use it if the file is encoded in Latin-1, but you should switch to UTF-8 as soon as possible.
2. The options `bibtotocnumbered` and `liststotoc` are deprecated.
3. `\underbrace{<code>}_{<code>}` should be braced in order to keep the correct spacing, so `{\underbrace{<code>}_{<code>}}`.
4. Never use `...` in the input, but `\dots` or, if needed, one among `\dotsc`, `\dotsb` or `\dotsm` (see [Difference of the \dots*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122491/4427)).

Comment: Based on your post here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446939/the-correct-layout-for-mathematical-derivations?noredirect=1#comment1122745_446939, how can I left aligned all the first equation inside alignat

Comment: @rook1996 I’ll check later

Comment: @rook1996 I'm not sure about left alignment: this should be a global decision, which can be obtained with the `fleqn` option.

Comment: just need it for the Appendix part and not global

Comment: @rook1996 Try with `\usepackage{nccmath}` in the preamble and `\leqn[0pt]` after `\appendix`.

Comment: Results into an error. I've changed now all my other derivations, thar are basing on flalign (and aligned) environments to be left aligned. However this derivation is still pending because of the alignat environment. May the informations, that only this derivation have to be left aligned helps somehow

Comment: @rook1996 Sorry, the correct command is `\fleqn[0pt]`

Comment: Nice one ! Is it possible to use the \fleqn just inside one section and then remove to the old "layout" ?

Comment: @rook1996 `\ceqn`, but in that case I'd prefer the environment form, see the documentation of `nccmath`.

Answer (score 6):

You need `alignat*`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, abstracton, bibtotocnumbered,liststotoc,12pt]{scrartcl}

%%%%% Betriebssystemabhängige Eingabedekodierung
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} %% für Windows
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\matr}[1]{\mathbf{#1}} 
\newcommand{\X}{\matr{X}} %Matrix von X
\newcommand{\y}{\matr{y}} %y als voller Vektor
\newcommand{\Xt}{\X^\mathbf{T}} %Matrix von X
\newcommand{\x}{\matr{x}}%Regressor von X
\newcommand{\xt}{\x^\mathbf{T}}%Regressor von X
\newcommand{\betahat}{\hat{\beta}} %betahat


\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\Xt\y-\Xt\X\betahat &= \lambda s && \\
\Leftrightarrow \underbrace{\Xt \y}_{p \times 1} &= \underbrace{\vphantom{\Xt\y}\lambda s}_{p\times1}, &&\quad s \in [-1,1]^{p} \\
\intertext{\textnormal{Das $j$-te Element entspricht}}
\xt_{j}\y &= \lambda s_j, &&\quad s_j \in [-1,1] \Leftrightarrow \lambda s_j \in [-\lambda, \lambda] \\
\Leftrightarrow  |\xt_{j}\y| &\leq \lambda, &&\quad \forall j \in \{1,...,p\}
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: I'll give you +1 for the slowness :-) of 30 sec.

Comment: Haha.. thanks, this time you won by a nose. Best thing actually about tex.sx is how people are helpful and responsive.

Answer (score 4):

Some layout improvements (at least for my taste): I used  `\underbracket` from `mathtools` in preference to  `\underbrace` which doesn't look so nice for small formulæ. Also, I used `\ArrowBetweenLines` (from mathtools again) – this adds another column in `alignat`. Last, I don't see why the  transposed symbol should be in boldface, so I used `\mathrm`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, abstracton, bibtotocnumbered,liststotoc,12pt]{scrartcl}

%%%%% Betriebssystemabhängige Eingabedekodierung
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %% für Windows
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\matr}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\X}{\matr{X}} %Matrix von X
\newcommand{\y}{\matr{y}} %y als voller Vektor
\newcommand{\Xt}{\X^\mathrm{T}} %Matrix von X
\newcommand{\x}{\matr{x}}%Regressor von X
\newcommand{\xt}{\x^\mathrm{T}}%Regressor von X
\newcommand{\betahat}{\hat{\beta}} %betahat

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
  & & \Xt\y-\Xt\X\betahat & = \lambda s\\
\ArrowBetweenLines
  & & \underbracket[0.4pt]{\Xt \y}_{p \times 1} & = \mkern-2mu\underbracket[0.4pt]{\mkern2mu \vphantom{\y}\lambda s\mkern1mu}_{p \times 1}\mkern-1mu, & \quad & s \in [-1,1]^{p} \\
  \intertext{\textnormal{Das $j$-te Element entspricht}}
 & & \xt_{j}\y &= \lambda s_j, & \quad & s_j \in [-1,1] \Leftrightarrow \lambda s_j \in [-\lambda, \lambda] \\
\ArrowBetweenLines
  & & |\xt_{j}\y| &\leq \lambda, & \quad & \forall j \in \{1,\dots,p\}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]