# Add a bracket in mathematical equation

Tags: align

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
     \usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,latexsym,mathrsfs,amsfonts,dsfont}
      \usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

    \begin{document}
    Let $\sigma_H(\mathbf{T})$ denote the Harte spectrum of $\mathbf{T}$ 
     i.e.
     $$\lambda=(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_d)\notin \sigma_H(\mathbf{T})$$
     $$ \Updownarrow $$
    $$ \exists (U_1,\cdots,U_d)\in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})^d\;\text{and}\; 
      (V_1,\cdots,V_d)\in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})^d \;\text{such that}\;$$
    $$\sum_{j=1}^dU_j(T_j-\lambda_jI)=I\;\text{and}\;\sum_{j=1}^d(T_j- 
    \lambda_jI)V_j=I.$$

      \end{document}
```

I get

[image]

I want to get

[image]

Comment: Your usage of double dollar signs is odd. You should use the LaTeX equivalents, or better something like `gather`.

Comment: Why not use a bmatrix env, one column

Comment: @daleif Unfortunalety I don't know how to use it. I hope that you provide me an answer.

Comment: It is the same thing as geza and joule is doing just simpler, the various matrix envs should be covered in any decent latex introduction. But come to thing of it, the bedt solution is gezas, as it is better semantically

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,latexsym,mathrsfs,amsfonts,dsfont}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\begin{document}
Let $\sigma_H(\mathbf{T})$ denote the Harte spectrum of $\mathbf{T}$  i.e.
\begin{gather*}
\left(\lambda=(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_d)\notin \sigma_H(\mathbf{T})\right)\\
\Updownarrow\\
\left[
\begin{gathered}
\exists (U_1,\cdots,U_d)\in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})^d\;\text{and}\; 
 (V_1,\cdots,V_d)\in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})^d \;\text{such that}\;\\
\sum_{j=1}^dU_j(T_j-\lambda_jI)=I\;\text{and}\;\sum_{j=1}^d(T_j- 
 \lambda_jI)V_j=I.
 \end{gathered}\right]
\end{gather*}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I wouldn't use parentheses around the top line, it's easy to remove them anyway.

Before going to the proposed solution, some remarks:

1. [Never, ever, use `$$` in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503).
2. Never, ever, use consecutive display math environments.
3. Don't load `latexsym`: its job is already done by `amssymb`.
4. `amssymb` already loads `amsfonts`.
5. Dots between commas should be low; using `\dots` will generally give you the right ones (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122497/4427)

A stylistic remark: using both `\mathcal` and `\mathscr` (from `mathrsfs`) can confuse readers.

In the code below I only load `amsmath`, the other packages are not necessary for this solution.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Let $\sigma_H(\mathbf{T})$ denote the Harte spectrum of $\mathbf{T}$  i.e.
\begin{gather*}
\bigl(\lambda=(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_d)\notin \sigma_H(\mathbf{T})\bigr)\\
\Updownarrow\\
\left[
\begin{tabular}{c}
  $\exists (U_1,\dots,U_d)\in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})^d$ and
  $(V_1,\dots,V_d)\in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})^d$ such that \\
  $\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^dU_j(T_j-\lambda_jI)=I$ and
  $\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^d(T_j-\lambda_jI)V_j=I$.
\end{tabular}
\right]
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Differences from the good answer by GézàLaTeX:

1. the top line is surrounded by slightly bigger parentheses (but, as said, I think they should be removed);
2. for the bottom block I think it's better using `tabular` that frees from juggling with `\text`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your great answer. So in my codes of my original document I keep only `\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,dsfont,mathrsfs} \usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}` Do you agree with me?

Comment: @Schüler I find the font provided by `dsfont` ugly as hell, but that's personal preference. Of course if you use it you never use `\mathbb`.

Comment: So should I delete `dsfont`? What about `\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}`? Is it good? I'm beginner in Latex and thank you for your great  help.

Comment: @Schüler If you don't use `\mathds`, then the package is redundant; `mathtools` offers facilities for typesetting math; `nccmath` offers others, which I find generally of little use. You can easily discover what packages of this kind you're using or not: remove them and compile again, if they are actually used in the document you'll receive errors. As a general advice: don't copy your friend's template.

Comment: @Schüler - The `mathtools` package loads the `amsmath` package automatically.

Comment: @Mico So can I delete `amsmath`? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Schüler - Yes -- as long as you load `mathtools`.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using `\[\]` instead of `$$ $$`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,latexsym,mathrsfs,amsfonts,dsfont}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\begin{document}
Let $\sigma_H(\mathbf{T})$ denote the Harte spectrum of $\mathbf{T}$ i.e.
$$\Big(\lambda=(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_d)\notin \sigma_H(\mathbf{T})\Big)$$
$$ \Updownarrow $$
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
    \exists (U_1,\cdots,U_d)\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})^d\;\text{and}\; 
    (V_1,\cdots,V_d)\in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})^d \;\text{such that}\\
    \displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^dU_j(T_j-\lambda_jI)=I\;\text{and}\;\sum_{j=1}^d(T_j- 
    \lambda_jI)V_j=I.
\end{array}
\right]
$$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You recommend, but you don't show? How about using an `amsmath` environment? ;-)

Comment: @Johannes_B I want to show that `$$ $$` is also correct. I don't use `\[ \]` because I'm afraid the OP will think that it is impossible to do the same with `$$ $$`. Anyway, thanks for your feedback!

Comment: @JouleV Why `\[\]` is better that `$$ $$`?Thanks.

Comment: @Schüler [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)