# How can I made \dots command smarter?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I have used in my document `\dots` instead of almost all other dots such as `\cdots`, `\ldots`. though it is smart in choosing base line depend on the formula, but in some cases it is not as (at least my) desired:

1. `\dots` cannot produce smart space e.g. `(1, \dots, n)` which prints `(1,\ldots,n)` which have not a space before tridots `(1, ...,n)'.
2. I don't know this case is correct typographically or not. but `\dots` in `1+2+\dots+n+\dots` produces `1+2+\cdots+n+\ldots` that I think last `\ldots` must be `\cdots`. isn't?

> **Question:** How can I redefine `\ldots` or define new one with above properties?

Comment: Do you load `amsmath`? Its manual says on p. 14 `For most situations, the undifferentiated \dots can be used, and amsmath will output the most suitable form based on the immediate context; if an inappro- priate form results, it can be corrected after examining the output.`, so they at least claim that `\dots` is smart after `amsmath` got loaded. Whether their and your conventions agree, I do not know.

Comment: yeah, I am using `amsmath`. unfortunately  I never read its manual.

Comment: for first one I have checked with `\dotsc` its not work. Is it correct typographically the first one?

Comment: Honestly, I do not know. All I wanted to say that there was already some effort to make `\dots` smarter.

Comment: Is there any obstruction for doing this?

Comment: I do not know. It would have to scan what is around it and be able to interpret these data. Doesn't sound simple to me.

Comment: Spaces before the dots are not generally used; the correct way for a “nonterminating sum” is `1+2+\dots+n+\dotsb`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122491/4427

Comment: @egreg, your reputation is much much overflow (it is frightening) and I ought  accept  your comment without hesitating.

Comment: @C.F.G It's not mandatory. `;-)` There are diverse typographical traditions: look in good books and decide what to do.