# Should I use cdots or ldots for an enumerated product?

Tags: typography, best-practices

What would be typografically right?

```
a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdots a_n
```

or

```
a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot a_n
```

[image]

Comment: Personally I use `\cdots`, but not the single `\cdot` which is usually quite unnecessary.

Comment: I would personally write it the second way, `\cdot \ldots \cdot`, for consistency with how I write addition and other binary  operations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference of the \dots\*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122491/difference-of-the-dots)

Comment: I believe the AMS would recommend `\dots`, which would get interpreted as `\dotsm`, which would become `\cdots`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion `a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdots a_n` is incorrect, `\cdot` is the operator, so repeating it like that makes no mathematical sense and can only be confusing.

It is generally accepted that `\ldots` stands for something that fills up the gap between two things, so definitely `a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot a_n`.

The AMS also recommends using `\ldots` for readability. As you can see in the exception in the image below from the [2017 AMS](https://www.ams.org/publications/authors/AMS-StyleGuide-online.pdf), page 103.[image: AMS 2017 page 103]

Answer (score 3):

[AMS Style Guide](https://www.ams.org/publications/authors/AMS-StyleGuide-online.pdf), pag 103:  Centered dots (cdots) are used between operators and relations. So AMS prefers `a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdots a_n`.

Answer (score 2):

This is largely a question of style. I would tend to use `$a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n$` for a repeated product, unless there was an explicit use of `\cdot` as an operator, e.g., if I were writing about operations on a group (*G*, •). For other operators, I would prefer `\cdots` between the repeated operators, e.g., `$a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n$` but if the operator is `\cdot`, I would leave the instances of `\cdot` surrounding the `\cdots` out. To my eye, `\ldots` looks wrong in this context, but again, the final decision is one of style and different publishers may have different expectations.