# Define a \dots-aware command

Tags: amsmath, babel, xparse

*edit:* changed the MWE to show the problem with french babel

So, I was wondering about in TeX.sx and came upon this question
[How do magic \dots work in amsmath?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/649/how-do-magic-dots-work-in-amsmath),
I wanted to do the same thing (have a `\dots`-aware macro).

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\renewcommand*{\to}{%
    \DOTSB
    \myto
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\myto}{o}{%
    \IfValueTF{#1}{%
        \xrightarrow{#1}%
    }{%
        % default latex \to
        \mathchar"3221
    }%
}

\begin{document}
\(t\to[s]\dots\to[b]a\)
\end{document}
```

but the dots don't adapt. I did:

```
texdef -t latex -p amsmath DOTSB
```

and apparently `\DOTSB` is `\relax`, and the amsmath.sty file confirm this.
Does anyone have a solution for this?

**edit**: I went with @egreg solution, because the other two conflicted with the `split` environment of `amsmath`.

Comment: That is because `texdef` is (like TeX itself) case sensitive: `texdef -t latex -p amsmath dotsb` yields `\dotsb: macro:->\protect \cdots`

Comment: `\dotsb` is a semantic macro for 'dots for binary operator', I was talking about `\DOTSB` wich is (if I understood right) a macro used in `amsmath.sty` to define commands wich make `\dots` behave like `\cdots`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a bug in the `french` module of `babel`. The `\dots` command is redefined to be

```
\relax\csname\ifmmode M\else T\fi dots@\endcsname
```

so in math mode `\Mdots@` is executed, which expands to `\@xp\mdots@`, which is wrong: it should simply be `\mdots@`. Indeed, patching `\dots` gives the expected result:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% the redefinition of \dots happens at begin document
% we simply remove one step: instead of the faulty
% \Mdots@ we do \mdots@
\AtBeginDocument{\xpatchcmd{\dots}{M}{m}{}{}}

\renewcommand*{\to}{%
    \DOTSB
    \myto
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\myto}{o}{%
    \IfValueTF{#1}{%
        \xrightarrow{#1}%
    }{%
        % default latex \to
        \rightarrow
    }%
}

\begin{document}
\(t\to[s]\dots\to[b]a\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If it's a bug I expect a bug report to Jazos :-)

Answer (score 4):

`\dots` of `amsmath` checks the next token and also checks the meaning of the next macro if necessary, if it starts with `\DOTSB`. The parsing for an optional argument prevents this detection, because it is implemented by more than one macro (mainly because of `\futurelet`). Therefore `\dots` does not see `\DOTSB`, the marker used by `\dots`. The example splits the macro in an expandable part for `\DOTSB` and the other part for the arrow and the optional argument:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\renewcommand*{\to}{%
    \DOTSB
    \myto
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\myto}{o}{%
    \IfValueTF{#1}{%
        \xrightarrow{#1}%
    }{%
        % default latex \to
        \mathchar"3221
    }%
}

\begin{document}
\(t\to[s]\dots\to[b]a\)
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### `\usepackage[french]{babel}`

This does not work for `frenchb.ldf`, because it redefines `\dots` and the definition of `amsmath` is gone.

The following example restores the `\dots` macro of `amsmath` inside math mode:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\LetLtxMacro\amsmathdots\dots

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \LetLtxMacro\frenchdots\dots
  \everymath{\LetLtxMacro\dots\amsmathdots}%
  \everydisplay{\LetLtxMacro\dots\amsmathdots}%
}

\renewcommand*{\to}{%
    \DOTSB
    \myto
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\myto}{o}{%
    \IfValueTF{#1}{%
        \xrightarrow{#1}%
    }{%
        % default latex \to
        \mathchar"3221
    }%
}

\begin{document}
\(t\to[s]\dots\to[b]a\)
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly with the MWE, but when I tried it with the acctual document, it didn't. Apparently, there is a conflict with french babel, do you have any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: Also, I would really love to understand why the `texdef` command returns `\relax`.

Comment: @shilluc: Make a minimal example that shows the problem.

Comment: @shilluc: `\DOTSB` is just used as marker for the previous `\dots` command. It does not need to do anything just sitting at the begin of the macro.

Answer (score 3):

A solution without `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{letltxmacro,amsmath}
\LetLtxMacro\amsdots\dots
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \LetLtxMacro\frenchdots\dots
  \everymath{\LetLtxMacro\dots\amsdots}%
  \everydisplay{\LetLtxMacro\dots\amsdots}%
}
\renewcommand*\to{\DOTSB\myto}
\newcommand*\myto[1][]{\if$#1$\dots\else\xrightarrow{#1}\fi}

\begin{document}
\( t\to[s]\dots\to[b]a \to\)
\end{document}
```

[image]