# How can I make amsmath's \dots look ahead after macro expansion?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

As [explained](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122497/71531) by egreg, "`amsmath` redefines `\dots` so that it can do a lookahead in order to establish what kind of dots to use." However, I noticed that this feature of `\dots` doesn't work when I define macros in place of commands that `\dots` would otherwise recognize. For example,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\by}{\times}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
A = A_1 \times \dots \times A_n \\
B = B_1 \by \dots \by B_m
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

produces the output

[image: dots]

The dots between the pairs of `\times` are in the correct position, whereas the dots between the pairs of `\by` are not. I'm guessing this is because `\dots` did a lookahead before macro expansion? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: `\let\by=\times`

Comment: Related [How do magic \dots work in amsmath?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/649/35864)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\by}{\times}
\let\olddots\dots
\def\dots{\expandafter\olddots\romannumeral`\^^@}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
A = A_1 \times \dots \times A_n \\
B = B_1 \by \dots \by B_m
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This breaks when `\boldsymbol{\times}\dots\boldsymbol{\times}` is tried.

Comment: @egreg true but it does what was asked, do the test after expansion.

Answer (score 8):

The standard way with `amsmath` is using `\DOTSB` inside the macro (`\dots` looks ahead for `\DOTSB`).

**Note**: I don't know why it's important that the macro is not `\long` so it works, hence the asterisk in `\newcommand*` is *mandatory* (which is correct anyways).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand*{\by}{\DOTSB\times}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
A = A_1 \times \dots \times A_n \\
B = B_1 \by \dots \by B_m
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

To make the AMS test skip over `\long` :

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\by}{\DOTSB\times}

\makeatletter
{\uccode`5=`m \uccode`6=`a \uccode`7=`c
\uccode`8=`\\ \uccode`9=`l \uccode`+=`o
 \uppercase{\gdef\macro@#1#2#3#4\macro@{\gtest@false
  \ifx 5#1\ifx 6#2\ifx 7#3\gtest@true
  \xdef\meaning@{\macro@@#4\macro@@}\fi\fi
  \else
  \ifx 8#1\ifx 9#2\ifx +#3\gtest@true
  \xdef\meaning@{\macro@@#4\macro@@}\fi\fi\fi
\fi}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
A = A_1 \times \dots \times A_n \\
B = B_1 \by  \dots \by B_m
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: amsmath 2.15 released this week includes a similar code that makes it ignore `\long`