# Inconsistent spacing of \dots and … with amsmath

Tags: spacing, amsmath, ellipsis

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2026}{\dots}% …
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[\left\{a \dots \right\}\]
\[\left\{a … \right\}\]

\end{document}
```

The spacing around the ellipsis is not the same for `\dots` and `…` in the document above (the third case is if I remove the `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2026}{\dots}`):

[image: The unicode ellipsis has less space to the right with \DeclareUnicodeCharacter. It has has no space to the left (but the correct spacing to the right I think) without the \DeclareUnicodeCharacter]

How can I get the same spacing with `\dots` and `…`? Hopefully this can be done without changing anything in the formula itself, just in the `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` code, as otherwise I'm likely to forget the hack most of the time, and the formulas are less concise.

The problem disappears if I'm not using `amsmath`.

Comment: Just a guess: Does replacing `\dots` by `\dots{}` in the `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` solve the problem?

Comment: @crixstox Good idea, but unfortunately it doesn't change anything :-( . Also, it looks like something smaller than an actual space. I'm more interested in the explanation of why this happens, though. As a quick fix I can always add a `\,` in the `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter`, and hope that it doesn't cause extraneous spacing in other cases.

Comment: @crixstox No, that would ruin the working of `\dots` that looks at the following token to decide if it should become `\ldots` or `\cdots`.

Comment: @egreg I didn't no that. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @GeorgesDupéron It's curious, because the usage of `…` doesn't break the choice between `\cdots` and `\ldots`; I tried `a+…+b` and `a,…,b` and got the expected behavior. However, it seems to be specific with `\}`, because if you try `(a\dots)` and `(a…)` you get the same spacing.

Comment: @egreg try `a+… +b` :-)

Answer (score 6):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2026}{\dots}% …
% \u8:… ->\IeC {\dots }
\expandafter\def\csname u8:\detokenize{…}\endcsname#1{\dots#1}


\begin{document}


$\left\{a \dots \right\}$\vline

$\left\{a … \right\}$\vline

\end{document}
```

`\dots` looks ahead at the next token to see whether to use low or centered dots.  `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` wraps its definition in `\IeC{...}` where `\IeC` (here) is just a macro that does nothing but use its argument.

But the main problem is that `\dots` uses `\futurelet` (rather than say `\@ifnextchar` ) so it does not skip over white space while looking for the next token. this does not usually matter for `\dots` as white space is ignored after a command name, but not after ... (which is the issue that `\IeC` addresses, to make sure that input enc characters don't have definitions that end with a token that forces white space to be ignored if written to an external file such as table of contents.

So here I define ... to take an argument and return it which is a (more or less safe) way to force space after the character to be ignored, so the `\dots` tests see `\}` not a space. The only unsafe part about that is that `{…}` would give a parse error as the argument parser would hit the end of group while looking for `#1`.

Comment: This works well, except in one case: if you write `\begin{document} {…} \end{document}`, it will complain because `…` has no argument. Nice to see how utf8 is handled :) .

Comment: @GeorgesDupéron hey I was writing that:-)

Comment: It seems `\def\mydots#1{\dots#1}\expandafter\def\csname u8:\detokenize{…}\endcsname{\@ifnextchar\egroup{\expandafter\dots}{\expandafter\mydots}}` does the trick, but I'm not sure if everything is working the way it should in the internals.

Comment: Another one to fix. Apart from using `\@ifnextchar` to ignore spaces, [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/266718/21930) should also be fixed (i.e., work even if next token is `\long`).

Comment: @Manuel it's a secret but the version of amsmath.sty I used to make the above is OK with \long tokens:-)

Comment: @GeorgesDupéron simpler you could do `\expandafter\def\csname u8:\detokenize{…}\endcsname{\@ifnextchar\dots\dots}` and avoid the dangerous `#1` lookahead. `\@ifnextchar` skips over white space you don't actually care what it finds as you can do `\dots`` in both cases/