# Context-aware dots at the end of formulas

Tags: spacing, amsmath

`amsmath` defines `\dots` which does a look-ahead and it uses different dots (vertically centred or not, basically) depending on the next token. See [How do magic \dots work in amsmath?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/649/63917)

However, because of this (at least, this is my understanding), it does not work when the dots are *at the end* of the formula:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[ x + \dots + x + \dots \]

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe.jpg]

Now, it is not a big deal when using `+` because I can directly use `\dotsb`. However, custom commands can also be made "dots-aware":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\newcommand*\myop{\DOTSB\rightarrow}

\[ x \myop \dots \myop x \myop \dots \]

\end{document}
```

In this case I would like the last `\dots` to automatically adjust itself depending on the definition of `\myop`. How can this be done?

I do not necessarily expect `\dots` to "remember" what happened before (though it would be nice), it would be ok to give it some kind of hint by repeating the operator after the dots:

```
\[ x \myop \dots \myop x \myop \dots \hint\myop \]
```

EDIT: or even better:

```
\[ x \myop \dots \myop x \myop \dotsfor{\myop} \]
```

Maybe a look-ahead macro looking at the first token of its argument could be used? Though it would not be just look-ahead, the rest of the argument should be discarded.

Comment: Why don’t you just use `\dotsb` for this one occurrence?  Any automated solution will have corner cases and frankly `\dots\hint\myop` is much longer to type than `\dotsb`.

Comment: @HenriMenke Because if I decide to change `\myop` then I have to find and replace all those occurrences of `\dotsb`.

Comment: Why not have `\def\myopdots{\myop\dotsb}` then?

Comment: @HenriMenke That is not too bad, though then two macros would need to be defined for each operator. I thought that a macro taking only the first token of its argument and discarding the rest could work...

Answer (score 4):

this doesn't seem to be explained in any readily available documentation, but there
*is* an explanation in *the joy of tex* (the manual for ams-tex) which is where the
dot variations were first defined.  from p.156:

> Thus, when you use `\dots` in math mode, the particular kind of dots
>   to be typeset is determined both by the style of and by the next
>   symbol in the formula. Unfortunately, there is one situation where
>   this scheme fails, namely, when there
>   *isn't* any next symbol.  If you type
>   [examples showing `\dots` at the end of a formula]
>   then `\dots` can't be expected to know which sorts
>   of dots you want -- it can only look ahead, and has no way of knowing
>   what symbol was typed before it -- and `\dots` simply chooses `\dotso`
>   in all those cases.  So when a formula ends with dots, the proper
>   thing to do is to tell AMS-TeX which sort of dots it should be using.

at the time ams-tex was created, this problem was thought about carefully, and
the edge cases were too unpredictable to consider.

i think the two-macro approach is your best option: `\myop` and `\myopdots` (or
other, possibly shorter, name for the second); easy to find in your file if you
need to change.

**edit:** as pointed out by @Zarko in a comment, `\dotsm` (for "multiplication dots") would be appropriate, as would `\dotsb` ("dots with binary operators/relations").  both resolve to `\cdots`.

Comment: Good reference! Since I am not very comfortable with the most technical issues of (La)TeX, may I ask you what is so hard/dangerous/unpredictable (or maybe just plain wrong) about implementing the idea I put in my edit?

Comment: @effeffe -- the code necessary to implement this could be rather complicated, and it would still not likely catch all the possible edge cases. thus it's not really "cost effective".  the fact that tex is a "one-way" system -- it can't backtrack -- does make this inconvenient, but knuth did comment in the *texbook* that exceptions of this sort are not all that frequent, and best handled on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, in OP case the `\dotsm` defined `amsmath` seems to be a solution: `\[ x + \dots + x + \dotsm \]` or even more cosistent `\[ x + \dotsm + x + \dotsm \]` .

Comment: @Zarko -- yes, it should be.  information added.  thanks.  however, take a look at section 4.3, p.12, of the `amsmath` user's guide, which recommends `\dotsb` associated with plus signs.

Comment: @Zarko That is what I already wrote in my answer: it was just an example, the problem is about user-defined operators, which could be either "low" (like commas) or "vertically centred" (like plus).

Comment: *I meant "question", sorry.