# How to prevent amsmath's \dots from adding extra space to a custom \set macro?

Tags: spacing, amsmath

I've written a custom `\set` macro to typeset sets allowing line breaks at every comma:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{amsmath} %<-- (un)comment to toggle the problem


% this is the colon in expressions like {n : n < 10}
\newcommand*{\setgiven}[1][]{%              #1 is discarded
  \nonscript\medspace\mathord:\allowbreak%  medspace? + : + break?
  \nonscript\medspace\mathopen{}%           medspace?
}

% \parseset splits a comma-separated list like
% 1,2,3,4,5
% into a sequence stored in \g_setlist_seq
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g_setlist_seq
\cs_new_nopar:Npn \parseset #1 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \g_setlist_seq { , } { #1 }
}
% \printset prints list \g_setlist_seq with
% each element separated by  ,\allowbreak
\cs_new_nopar:Npn \printset {
  \seq_use:Nnnn \g_setlist_seq {,\allowbreak}{,\allowbreak}{,\allowbreak}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\set}{s o m}{%
  % \set{1,2,3} => simple set that allows line breaks at commas
  % \set[n]{n<10} => {n : n < 10}
  % the starred versions use \left\{ and \right\} to handle "tall" characters
  \parseset{#3}%
  \IfValueTF{#2}  % WITH optional argument
  {\IfBooleanTF{#1}  % starred: \left and \right
    {\left\lbrace #2\setgiven[\delimsize] \printset \right\rbrace}%
    {\lbrace #2\setgiven[\delimsize] \printset \rbrace}%
  }
  % WITHOUT optional argument
  {\IfBooleanTF{#1}  % starred: \left and \right
    {\left\lbrace \printset \right\rbrace}
    {\lbrace \printset \rbrace}%
  }%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{r l}
  With \string\mathellipsis & $\set{1, 2, \mathellipsis}$\\
  With \string\dots & $\set{1, 2, \dots}$\\
  %With \string\dotsc & $\set{1, 2, \dotsc}$\\ %<-- uncomment when using amsmath
  With \string\dots\string\relax & $\set{1, 2, \dots\relax}$\\
  With \string\dots\{\} & $\set{1, 2, \dots{}}$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This macro should behave well with `amsmath`, because it's a very common package.
It's also very common to write sets such as `\set{1, 2, \dots}`, so the macro should also behave well with `\dots` at the end.

I've found out that while the macro is ok with standard LaTeX,
ending a `\set` with `\dots` adds some extra space if you're using `amsmath`
(`\dots` in the middle of other things, as in `\set{1, \dots, n}`, is fine).

Regular LaTeX:

[image]

With `amsmath`:

[image]

After examining `amsmath.sty` and
reading a [few](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/351342/90645) [questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/649/90645) here,
I know the `amsmath` version of `\dots` examines the next token to
decide which kind of dots to use,
but I don't know why in this case it adds extra space.

There's a way to prevent this,
using something else at the end of a `\set`:
`\dots\relax` and `\mathellipsis` work, but
`\dots{}` and `\dotsc` don't
(which is not very intuitive, I think people would expect all four of these to work).

So, *is there a way to allow a user using `amsmath` to simply type `\dots` and
don't get the extra space*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as you show a trailing `\relax` is enough, so you can supply one, it won't affect anything apart from this lookahead.

```
  \parseset{#3\relax}%
              %%%%%%
```