# Spacing of relation and operation symbols with propositions

Tags: math-mode, spacing, relation-symbols

LaTeX follows typographic standards and does an elegant job of correctly spacing relation symbols like "=" or "∈" and operation symbols like "+" or "∧". For example, in

`$a + b  =  x + y$`

LaTeX adds more space around "=" than around "+", so that the expression is correctly interpreted as "(a+b)=(x+y)" and not as "a+(b=x)+y" – which is meaningless. See § 3.1 of Downes's [Short Math Guide](http://ftp.cvut.cz/tex-archive/info/short-math-guide/).

Consider, though, relations and operations between *propositions* that involve equalities. For example, we want to say that the equality of `a` and `b` implies the equality of `x` and `y`. Writing directly

`$a  =  b \Rightarrow x  =  y$`

or

`$a  =  b \mathop{\Rightarrow} x  =  y$`

would yield the wrong spacing, suggesting "a=(b⇒x)=y". A way to fix this could be by somehow adding quotation marks around the propositions, to obtain something like

`"a = b" ⇒ "x = y"`

but this expression looks cluttered. Of course one can also add/remove spacing by hand – but how much?

An even more complex situation appears with probability formulae, for example if we want to say that the equality of `a` and `b` is as likely as that of `x` and `y`, or consider the sum of the two:

`$P(a = b)  =  P(x = y)$`

`$P(a = b)  +  P(x = y)$`

My question is twofold:

– What are the typesetting rules in cases like these?

– How do LaTeX users (who care about correct spacing) approach this problem?

I'd be happy to know about consistent and elegant solutions.

Cheers!

Comment: I suppose this is why `amsmath` defines `\implies`, `\iff` and `\impliedby` as `\DOTSB\;\Longrightarrow\;`, `\DOTSB\;\Longleftrightarrow\;` and `\DOTSB\;\Longleftarrow\;` respectively.

Comment: I didn't know this, thank you for the great information. Is there a difference between `\DOTSB` and `\dotsb`?

Comment: `\DOTSB` itself doesn't actually do anything; it is just a marker for `amsmath`'s "magic" `\dots` (which can look like either `\cdots` or `\ldots`, depending on the character following it). See e.g. [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/660/156366).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I could then define `\DOTSB\;=\;`, `\DOTSB\;\land\;` and `\DOTSB\;+\;` to work in cases like `$a=b \land x=y$` and `$P(a=b) = P(x=y)$`, I suppose.

Comment: Yup, that'd work!

Comment: Could you turn your comment into an answer, so that I can accept it? Cheers.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if I can truly answer the question because I don't actually know if there is a typesetting rule mandating the insertion of this extra space, or whether `\implies` et al. are used much.

Comment: I was also asking for elegant solutions, and yours is one. I'd be happy to accept it as an answer, and I'm sure other people would find it useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### My (personal) thoughts on the matter

I don't know of any typographical rules for this, but I think adding additional space around relations or operations *between* propositions makes a lot of sense because these operate at a different level in some sense.
So I would probably add some space around the arrow in `$a=b \Rightarrow x=y$`, and I might do the same thing for `a=b \land x=y` (though I probably wouldn't in an inline equation).

I don't believe the same thing applies to probabilities, however, since these are just numbers. 
I think adding extra space to either `P(a=b) + P(x=y)$` or `P(a=b) = P(x=y)$` is unnecessary and actually a little inconsistent.
You can always add space for the sake of legibility, but I don't see any syntactic reason for it.

### About `implies`, `\impliedby` and `\iff`

The `amsmath` package (which you are likely already using) actually defines the macros `\implies`, `\iff` and `\impliedby` as versions of `\Longrightarrow`, `\Longleftrightarrow` and `\Longleftarrow` that insert some extra space on either side (though `\iff` actually also works without `amsmath`.)
You can see them in action here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[P \implies Q \iff R \impliedby S\]
\[P \Longrightarrow Q \Longleftrightarrow R \Longleftarrow S\]
\end{document}
```

[image: arrow comparison]

These commands are defined as `\DOTSB\;\Longrightarrow\;`, `\DOTSB\;\Longleftrightarrow\;` and `\DOTSB\;\Longleftarrow\;` respectively.
The important part is `\;`, which [inserts a `\thickmuskip`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74354/156366) and effectively doubles the amount of space around these arrows.
`\DOTSB` doesn't really do anything; it is just a marker that tells `amsmath`'s ["magic" `\dots`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/649/156366) that this is a binary operator/relation.

If you think `\implies` et al. are a little too long by default, you can redefine these with

```
\renewcommand\implies{\DOTSB\;\Rightarrow\;}
\renewcommand\impliedby{\DOTSB\;\Leftarrow\;}
\renewcommand\iff{\DOTSB\;\Leftrightarrow\;}
```

and you could similarly define versions of your favourite symbols that add more space with

```
\newcommand\metasomesymbol{\DOTSB\;<somesymbol>\;}
```

You can leave out `\DOTSB` if you don't use `\dots` and are sure you never will, but including it consistently requires relatively little effort.

The same thing can of course also be accomplished by adding a pair of `\;` every time (as long as there are no `\dots` around).

### Suggestion

Since I (personally) think all this extra space would actually be rather unpleasant in inline equations, here is a way to define symbols that only get extra space in display style.
I'm using `\mathchoice` to do this.
An explanation of how this works can be found e.g. in the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/148740/156366).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*\mathmeta[1]{\DOTSB\mathchoice{\;#1\;}{#1}{#1}{#1}}
\newcommand*\newmetasymbol[2]{\newcommand#1{\DOTSB\mathmeta{#2}}}
\newcommand*\renewmetasymbol[2]{\renewcommand#1{\DOTSB\mathmeta{#2}}}

\renewmetasymbol\implies{\Rightarrow}
\renewmetasymbol\impliedby{\Leftarrow}
\renewmetasymbol\iff{\Leftrightarrow}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\newmetasymbol\nimplies{\nRightarrow}
\newmetasymbol\nimpliedby{\nLeftarrow}
\newmetasymbol\niff{\nLeftrightarrow}

\begin{document}

This is an inline equation: $x=y \implies x^2=y^2 \iff y^2=x^2 \impliedby y=x$.

This is a displayed equation:
\[
    x=y \implies x^2=y^2 \iff y^2=x^2 \impliedby y=x.
\]

Here are a few more symbols: $(x = y \mathmeta{\land} y = z) \implies x = z$, but
\[
    (x = y \mathmeta{\lor} y = z) \nimplies x = z
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: +1 for such a comprehensive answer!

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. I agree on what you say about probabilities. The commands for little shorter implication arrows are great, I'll use those indeed. And I didn't know about `\mathchoice`, thank you for that too!