# Correct spacing for beautiful and readable logical expressions

Tags: spacing, typography, logic

I am looking for generally accepted standards or "best practices" on how to space logical expressions. I am particularly interested in expressions of the form:

[image]

My question arose after I read the following principle somewhere in this site: *there should be more space around more important elements*. In the equation `a + b = c`, the relation `=` is more important than the binary operation `+`, and therefore, it makes sense to have more space around it. That is why `\mathrel{}` adds more space than `mathbin{}`.

However, in the logical expression `(a=b \land b=c) \implies a=c`, I am not sure that `=` is the most important element. Here, my intuition tells me that `\land` should have more space than `=`, and maybe `\land` and `\implies` should have a similar amount of space. Without it, there might be ambiguity between `((a=b)\land(b=c))` and `(a = (b\land b) = c)`. However, the default space is `\mathrel{}` for `=`, `\mathbin{}` for `\land`, and something that looks bigger for `\implies`.

I would like to know the answer to the following specific questions

1. Are there any style manuals that address the best practices on how to space logical expressions?
2. What are some generally accepted principles on how to set space around binary relations, conjunctions, and implications in displayed logical formulas?
3. If using `\text{and}` inside a displayed logical formula, what is the right amount of space to use around it?
4. Why does LaTeX assign different space to `\implies` and `\iff` but not `\land` and `\lor`?

I understand that some of these questions could be opinion-based. I hope this question does not go against any community policies.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
    (a=b \land b=c) \implies a=c
\]
\[
    (a=b\ \text{and}\ b=c) \implies a=c
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14189/what-are-or-where-can-i-find-style-guidelines-for-writing-math) has some good advice on general math style guides if that helps. I, however, would use consistent spacing in accordance with my personal taste.

Comment: Hi, I just found someone else asked the same question and got the answer I needed here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472720/spacing-of-relation-and-operation-symbols-with-propositions  Thank you!