# How to find the previously printed character?

Tags: macros

Is there a way to find the previously printed character in LaTeX? E.g:

```
\newcommand{\th}{%
  \ifthenelse%
    {\equal{\previouscharacter}{1}}%
    {st}%
    {th}%
}

4\th and 21\th % would like to yield "4thand 21st"
```

Comment: Nice question! Nevertheless, [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4118/whats-the-quickest-and-easiest-way-to-write-2nd-3rd-etc-in-latex/4119#4119) may be of interest to you.

Comment: @lockstep: Actually, I just read that question and thought: wouldn't `n\th` look better than `\nth{n}`?

Comment: @Tim: `n\th` would gobble any space that follows in the text, so ... probably not. ;-)

Comment: Ah well, with some minor modifications then.

Comment: I'm not sure how this would work. TeX wouldn't know that it would need to remember the character before until after it has read it...

Comment: @Seamus: I don't know the inner workings of TeX. Theoretically, it could always remember or be able to backtrack.

Comment: See also: [boxes - Determining the most-recently-read or most-recently-output character - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397644/determining-the-most-recently-read-or-most-recently-output-character) // [tex core - Reading the contents of a box - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6183/reading-the-contents-of-a-box) // [logging - \showbox and log file - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103684/showbox-and-log-file)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer, unfortunately, is no. TeX contains a few primitives that modify things before them (`\over`, `\atop`, `\above` and the `withdelims` variants), but nothing general purpose.

In addition to the various packages which implement printing ordinal numbers, I wrote a fairly straightforward macro that does this [here](http://texhacks.blogspot.com/2010/04/ordinal-numbers.html).

Comment: I know nothing about `\lastbox`, but could it conceivably be used to do that?

Comment: @Bruno: alas, my experience as recorded in the following discussion suggests not: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6183/reading-the-contents-of-a-box/6186#6186.

Answer (score 3):

As to the specific application in question, there's the [engord package](http://ctan.org/pkg/engord). Examples:

```
\engordnumber{1} 
\engordnumber{12}
\engordnumber{123}
```

return 1st, 12th, and 123rd. For the specific question, I can't answer.

Answer (score 1):

LuaLaTeX solution:

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\directlua{assert(node.types()[29]=="glyph")}
\directlua{assert(node.types()[12]=="glue")}

\def\copylastchar{%
\directlua{%
a=node.last_node();%
if a==nil then tex.print("[!?]") else %
node.write(a);%
tex.print("["..(a.id==29 and utf8.char(node.getchar(a)) or a.id==12 and " " or "???").."]")%
end%
}}

abcd\copylastchar

1\copylastchar

1 \copylastchar

ab\setbox0=\hbox{c}\box0\copylastchar

ab\setbox0=\hbox{2}\raise 1mm\box0\copylastchar

\copylastchar


\end{document}
```

Output:

```
abcd[d]
1[1]
1 [ ]
abc[b]
ab²[b]
[!?]
```

The function `\copylastchar` takes the last character then re-print it to the document for the purpose of viewing.

Note that it's not always foolproof (as can be seen in the last examples where `b` is printed instead of `c` or `2`)

I don't know if there might be any disadvantage of getting the `last_node` then `write` it back like that.

Comment: Side note, do `\directlua{debug.debug()}` to spawn a Lua interactive prompt and play with it.