# \showbox and log file

Tags: auxiliary-files, logging

I want to parse the output of the `\showbox` command externally.  Is it possible to let `\showbox` write to another file than the .log file?  If not, is it possible to temporarily change the name of the .log file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid the answer is 'no': TeX is hard-wired to write to a `.log` file, and `\show...` commands write to the log. As such, you'll need to use some lateral thinking, for example using an auxiliary compilation just for the `\showbox` part or writing markers to surround the `\showbox` section of your log.

Comment: Thank you, Joseph.  So I'm going to write markers to extract the relevant parts later on.