# Determining the most-recently-read or most-recently-output character

Tags: boxes

Is there any way a macro can know either of the following?

- The last printable character TeX read from the source file
- The contents of the last character box TeX produced

Rationale: I am working on a XeLaTeX package that will support Stone Sans Phonetic, an old commercial IPA font. Stone Sans Phonetic was created before the Unicode era, and handles accents using *ligatures* rather than combining characters — that is, to put an **ø̂** on the page, you write code that prints the characters `ø` and `^` side-by-side, and the font has a ligature that combines them.

Unfortunately, some ligatures are missing. For instance, printing `n` and `^` side-by-side doesn't put an **n̂** on the page.

What I'd like to do, then, is use `\newunicodechar` to make a Unicode combining circumflex trigger a macro that does the following:

1. Determine whether the character to its left was one that will produce a ligature with `^`.
2. If it was, print a `^` in Stone Sans Unicode.
3. If it wasn't, print a Unicode combining circumflex in some fallback font.

Is this feasible?

(FWIW, I would have expected `\lastbox` to do what I'm looking for, but this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newbox\temp
a\setbox\temp=\lastbox
\showbox\temp
\end{document}
```

shows `\temp` to be void. What am I missing, and/or is there a different way to do what I need?)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please provide a MWE (minimal, but compilable code example) to help us help you?

Comment: Ok, I've expanded the last code block in my question to be compilable on its own. The behavior I wanted, with that code saved as `test.tex`, is that after running `xelatex test.tex` the file `test.log` would show `\temp` to contain a letter `a`. The behavior I saw is that `\temp` was shown to be void. I think this means I've misunderstood what `\lastbox` does, and I'd like to know if there is some other way of getting the behavior I wanted.

Comment: As far as i know, this kind of back-referencing on letter level is not possible in TeX. The only way i know of, is to write a macro which takes the next two tokens as arguments (that is, your letter and the diacritic) and to internally evaluate your character set against them, but i think this is not suitable for your purpose, is it?

Comment: A switch to lualatex is probably not an option, is it?

Comment: I'm making this package in the hope that it will be useful to others, so if lualatex offers better support for this feature I'd definitely look at taking advantage of it. 

In xelatex I do want to preserve the behavior that Unicode input Just Works as often as possible, so if xelatex doesn't offer a way to examine the last character, it probably makes sense to always use combining accents in a fallback font under xelatex.

Comment: The way to do that in xetex is probably to define a `.vf` virtual font that has the accents and use that , or to fix the font in fontforge or similar

Comment: characters do not make boxes so `\lastbox` does nothing to help here

Comment: With lualatex you could try to build a combo font (see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371647/call-a-luatex-combo-font-through-nfss). But I have some doubt that one can pull in combining accents.

Comment: Same question: [macros - How to find the previously printed character? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13326/how-to-find-the-previously-printed-character?noredirect=1&lq=1) (although there isn't any good solution either)

Answer (score 1):

This uses the `tokcycle` package to save the current token in the input stream, so that if the next token is a `^`, the saved token can be compared for ligature processing.

Without working with your actual font and problem, it is hard to say if this method will suffice.

In this MWE, I implement artificially constructed ligatures for `d^` and `n^`, within the `\StoneSansLigs` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\svd{d}
\def\svn{n}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\def\lastsslchar{}
\tokcycleenvironment\StoneSansLigs
{%
\ifx##1^
  \ifx\svd\lastsslchar\relax\addcytoks{$\hat{\textrm{d}}$}\fi% d^ ligature
  \ifx\svn\lastsslchar\relax\addcytoks{$\hat{\textrm{n}}$}\fi% n^ ligature
  \gdef\lastsslchar{}%
\else
  \addcytoks[1]{\lastsslchar}%
  \gdef\lastsslchar{##1}%
\fi
}
{\addcytoks[1]{\lastsslchar}\processtoks{##1\expandafter}%
  \addcytoks[1]{\lastsslchar}}
{\addcytoks[1]{\lastsslchar##1}\gdef\lastsslchar{}}
{\addcytoks[1]{\lastsslchar##1}\gdef\lastsslchar{}}
\begin{document}
\StoneSansLigs
abd^c \textbf{pdd^q} n^m
\endStoneSansLigs
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Characters do not make boxes, so `\lastbox` does not remove them from the current list. In fact there is really no way in classic tex or xetex to see the previous character (luatex would be a possibility).

One solution would be to make a virtual font (`.vf`) that had all the required ligatures, but a simpler and perhaps acceptable method is to use markup `\zzhat` here that adds appropriate commands in each case.

Here I have assumed that the font has an `a^` ligature (but the output is wrong in this case as I'm using latin modern) and for any characters not defined to use a ligature, a fallback (using the standard `\^` command) is used, as shown on `o` here.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\zhat#1{%
\ifcsname zhat-\string#1\endcsname
 \csname zhat-\string#1\endcsname
\else
  \^{#1}%
\fi}

%if a^ ligature is there and o^ is not....

% add lines for all characters to use ligature (or any other character-specific code)
\expandafter\edef\csname zhat-a\endcsname{a\string^}

\begin{document}


zzz \zhat{a} \zhat{o} zzz

\end{document}
```