# Latex \tracing commands list?

Tags: debugging

Often I need to recall the different `\tracing` commands; and a couple of times I stumbled on some webpages that worked fine for me; sadly, I didn't keep them, and my searches don't take me there anymore.

So I thought I'd ask about links to where one can read a list of `\tracing` commands?

For instance, [TRALICS : a LaTeX to XML translator (T)](http://www-sop.inria.fr/marelle/tralics/doc-t.html#cmd-tracingall) mentions:

```
\tracingall
\tracingassigns
\tracingcommands
\tracinggroups
\tracingifs
\tracinglostchars
\tracingmacros
\tracingnesting
\tracingonline
\tracingoutput
\tracingpages
\tracingparagraphs
\tracingrestores
\tracingstats
\tracingscantokens
```

.. but, I'm pretty sure there was something like `\tracingboxes` (*and not so sure if there was something like `\tracingglues`*); yet I cannot find any resources mentioning those.

Comment: *The TeXbook*, [`Tex for the Impatient`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/impatient) and the [`e-TeX`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etex) package documentation can be valuable resources for the `\tracing...` family.

Comment: Thanks for those links, @GonzaloMedina - they look really good! But I was hoping more for a quick, compehensive webpage list (_possibly with notes about where the commands come from, e.g. "tracingall" from Latex, "traceon" from `trace` package, etc.._) Thanks again - cheers!

Comment: I wish there was a `\tracingglues`!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Scanning the [TeX Book](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/knuth/dist/tex/texbook.tex) and the [TeX program](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/knuth/dist/tex/tex.web) provide the most detail with regards to the `\tracing...` commands. Also a list is provided online in the [TeX Primitive Control Sequences](http://www.tug.org/utilities/plain/cseq.html). The combined list includes:

- `\tracingcommands` [pi] if positive, writes commands to the `.log` file.
- `\tracinglostchars` [pi] if positive, writes characters not in the current font to the `.log` file.
- `\tracingmacros` [pi] if positive, writes to the `.log` file when expanding macros and arguments.
- `\tracingonline` [pi] if positive, writes diagnostic output to the terminal as well as to the `.log` file.
- `\tracingoutput` [pi] if positive, writes contents of shipped out boxes to the `.log` file.
- `\tracingpages` [pi] if positive, writes the page-cost calculations to the `.log` file.
- `\tracingparagraphs` [pi] if positive, writes a summary of the line-breaking calculations to the `.log` file.
- `\tracingrestores` [pi] if positive, writes save-stack details to the `.log` file.
- `\tracingstats` [pi] if positive, writes memory usage statistics to the `.log` file.
- `\tracingall` turns on every possible mode of interaction

Those marked with [pi] take a `p`arameter argument in the form of an `i`nteger. For example, one would use `\tracingcommands1`.

---

[e-TeX](http://tex.loria.fr/moteurs/etex_ref.html) introduces a number of new features in the form of:

- `\tracingassigns` [pi] When the program is compiled with the code for collecting statistics and `\tracingassigns` has a value of 1 or more, all assignments subject to TEX's
  grouping mechanism are traced.
- `\tracinggroups` [pi] a further aid to debugging runaway-group problems, `\tracinggroups` (an internal read/write integer) causes e-TeX to trace entry and exit to every group while set to a positive non-zero value.
- `\tracingifs` [pi] When `\tracingifs` has a value of 1 or more, all conditionals (including `\unless`, `\or`, `\else`, and `\fi`) are traced, together with the starting line and nesting level; the `\showifs` command displays the state of all currently active
  conditionals.
- `\tracingscantokens` [pi] an internal read/write integer, assigning it a positive non-zero value will cause an open-parenthesis and space to be displayed whenever `\scantokens` is invoked; the matching close-parenthesis will be recorded when the scan is complete. If a traceback occurs during the expansion of `\scantokens`, the first displayed line number will reflect the logical line number of the pseudo-file created from the parameter to `\scantokens`; thus enabling `\tracingscantokens` can assist in identifying why an seemingly irrational line number is shewn as the source of error (the traceback always continues until the line number of the actual source file is displayed).

These additions are explained in the [e-TeX system documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/e-tex/v2/doc/etex_man.pdf).

---

[TeX for the Impatient](http://ctan.org/pkg/impatient) *defines* `\tracingboxes`:

```
\def\tracingboxes{\showboxbreadth = \maxdimen
  \showboxdepth = \maxdimen}%
```

- `\tracingboxes` causes boxes to be displayed completely when they're traced. (TeX normally shows only three levels of boxing and ﬁve items within each box.)

---

The [`xcolor` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) adds `\tracingcolors` (from the [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf), section **2.13 Color Information**, p 28-29):

- `\tracingcolors=<int>` controls the amount of information that is written into the `.log` file:

  - `<int>` ≤ 0: no specific colour logging.
  - `<int>` ≥ 1: ignored colour definitions due to `\providecolor` are logged.
  - `<int>` ≥ 2: multiple (i.e. overwritten) colour definitions are logged.
  - `<int>` ≥ 3: every command that defines a colour will be logged.
  - `<int>` ≥ 4: every command that sets a colour will be logged.

---

The [`etoolbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) adds `\tracingpatches` (from the [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.pdf), section **3.4 Patching**, p 11-12):

> Also note that the commands in this section will not automatically issue any error messages if patching fails. Instead, they take a <*failure*> argument which should provide suitable fallback code or an error message. Issuing `\tracingpatches` in the preamble will cause the commands to write debugging information to the transcript file.
>
> [...]
>
> `\tracingpatches`
>
> Enables tracing for all patching commands, including `\ifpatchable`. The debugging information will be written to the transcript file. This is useful if the reason why a patch is not applied or `\ifpatchable` yields <*false*> is not obvious. This command must be issued in the preamble.

Analogously, [`regexpatch`](http://ctan.org/pkg/regexpatch) supplies `\tracingxpatches`.

---

[`multicol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol) defines the *counter* `tracingmulticols` that can be modified using `\setcounter{tracingmulticols}{<number>}`. From the [`multicol` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/multicol.pdf) (section **2.7 Tracing the output**, p 5):

> To understand the reasoning behind the decisions TeX makes when processing a `multicols` environment, a tracing mechanism is provided. If you set the counter `tracingmulticols` to a positive `<number>` you then will get some tracing information on the terminal and in the transcript file:
>
> `<number>` = 1. TeX will now tell you, whenever it enters or leaves a `multicols` environment, the number of columns it is working on and its decision about starting a new page before or after the environment.
>
> `<number>` = 2. In this case you also get information from the balancing routine: the heights tried for the left and right-most columns, information about shrinking if the `\raggedcolumns` declaration is in force and the value of the `unbalance` counter if positive.
>
> `<number>` = 3. Setting `<number>` to this value will additionally trace the mark handling algorithm. It will show what marks are found, what marks are considered, etc. To
>   fully understand this information you will probably have to read carefully trough the implementation.
>
> `<number>` >= 4. Setting `<number>` to such a high value will additionally place an `\hrule` into your output, separating the part of text which had already been considered
>   on the previous page from the rest. Clearly this setting should *not* be used for the final output. It will also activate even more debugging code for mark handling.

---

[`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) provides `\tracingtabularx` (section **4.1 Terminal output**, p 2, of the [`tabularx` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/tabularx.pdf)):

> If this declaration is made, say in the document preamble, then all following
>   `tabularx` environments will print information about column widths as they repeatedly reset the tables to find the correct widths.
>
> As an alternative to using the `\tracingtabularx` declaration, either of the options `infoshow` or `debugshow` may be given, either in the `\usepackage` command
>   that loads `tabularx`, or as a global option in the `\documentclass` command.

---

From [LaTeX News, Issue 21, May 2014](http://latex-project.org/ltnews/ltnews21.pdf):

For years the file [`ltoutput.dtx`](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/ltoutput.dtx) contained some hidden
code to trace the detailed behaviour of the float
placement algorithm of LaTeX. Prompted by questions
on StackExchange we now extract this code into a new
[`fltrace` package](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/fltrace.sty). To see the float algorithm in action (or
to understand why it decides to place all your floats at
the very end of the document) use

```
\usepackage{fltrace} \tracefloats
```

To stop tracing somewhere in the document use
`\tracefloatsoff` and to see the current value of
various float parameters use `\tracefloatvals`. As the
package is identical to the kernel code with tracing
added, it may or may not work if you load any other
package that manipulates that part of the kernel code.
In such a case your best bet is to load `fltrace` first.

---

The [`tracefnt` package](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/tracefnt.sty) provides for tracing the actions concerned with loading, substituting and using fonts. The package accepts the following options:

- `errorshow`

  Write all information about font changes, etc. but only to the transcript
  file unless an error occurs. This means that information about font
  substitution will not be shown on the terminal.
- `warningshow`

  Show all font warnings on the terminal. This setting corresponds
  to the default behaviour when this tracefnt package is not used!
- `infoshow`

  Show all font warnings and all font info messages (that are normally
  only written to the transcript file) also on the terminal. This is the default
  when this `tracefnt` package is loaded.
- `debugshow`

  In addition to what is shown by `infoshow`, show also changes of
  math fonts (as far as possible): beware, this option can produce a large
  amount of output.
- `loading`

  Show the names of external font files when they are loaded. This
  option shows only 'newly loaded' fonts, not those already preloaded in the
  format or the class file before this `tracefnt` package becomes active.
- `pausing`

  Turn all font warnings into errors so that LaTeX will stop.

*Warning*: The actions of this package can change the layout of a document and even, in rare cases, produce clearly wrong output, so it should not be used in the final formatting of 'real documents'.

---

`\pdftracingfonts` (pdfTeX):

> An integer variable controlling the tracing of font
>   expansion. It is zero by default; then we get a log (with fontexpansion)
>   like this
>
> `...\tenrm t`
>
> `...\tenrm (+20) e`
>
> Without font expansion, this default should be compatible with TeX's
>   original log output.
>   If `\pdftracingfonts` is set to `1` (or greater), we get a more verbose log:
>
> `...\xivtt (cmtt10@14.0pt) t`
>
> `...\xivtt (cmtt10+20@14.0pt) e`
>
> See also bug 304.

(https://www.tug.org/applications/pdftex/NEWS)

---

`\XeTeXtracingfonts` (XeTeX):

> If nonzero, reports where fonts are found in the log file.

(http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/xetexref/xetex-reference.pdf)

Comment: Many thanks for that list, @Werner! So all of these are tex built-ins, no e-tex (or etex) commands among them? (_note to self: cseq.html is quite a large page, and may take a bit to load_).

Comment: @sdaau: As far as I can tell, yes. I'll add some more about e-TeX.

Comment: Perfect, many thanks for the update @Werner; accepted now, as I believe the list now is as complete as it gets. (_now I just wish I could remember where I got that `\tracingboxes` from_ `:)`) Many thanks again - cheers!

Comment: You can add `\tracingboxes`; a description can be found  in *TeX for the Impatient*.

Comment: Great, thanks for that @GonzaloMedina - I was afraid I had otherwise imagined that command `:)` Cheers!

Comment: And there is also `\XeTeXtracingfonts=1`.

Comment: ... and `\pdftracingfonts`.

Comment: I just learned there is also `\tracefloats`; it's `.sty` file has to be manually generated, however, as described in [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX? #39020](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat/39020#39020)

Comment: Not yet in this list: LaTeX's `\showoutput`, which shows pages being shipped out: it activates `\tracingonline` (log diagnostic to terminal),`\tracingoutput` (dump shipped out boxes), `\tracingboxes` (show full box contents when dumping them),  and `\errorstopmode` (ask for input on errors).

Comment: For clarity, equal signs would be helpful at each command example, like `\tracingmacros=0/1`(off/on), as shown in the [linked reference](http://www.tug.org/utilities/plain/cseq.html#tracingmacros-rp)

Comment: (typo: shown → shewn.) —

Answer (score 0):

Some recent additions and modifications, according to [The TeX Live Guide](https://tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html).

TeX Live 2021 ([live link](https://tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-900009.1.18) in The TeX Live Guide---2023):

- `\tracinglostchars` (except in the Knuth TeX) results in errors instead of info if set to 3 or more.

  > if `\tracinglostchars` is set to 3 or more, missing characters will result in an error, not just a message in the log file, and the missing character code will be shown in hex.
- `\tracingstacklevels` (except in the Knuth TeX) was added.

  > `\tracingstacklevels`, if positive, and `\tracingmacros` is also positive, causes a prefix indicating the macro expansion depth to be output on each relevant log line (e.g., `~..` at depth 2). Also, macro logging is truncated at a depth ≥ the parameter value.