# Logfile very large

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, texstudio, logging

Everytime I compile my file, I get a message from TeXstudio saying

> The logfile is very large (> 2 MB) are you sure you want to load it?

This is mostly because I am updating the bibliography, while to a large extent the .bib file is not correctly formatted (it is simply an output from Endnote actually).

**My question is:** Is there any way for me to avoid getting the warning from TeXstudio and permanently assign that I want to load the log file? (otherwise, I am not able to see the Errors, and the bibliography is not even made).

**Edit:** It seems like the error is not coming from the bibliography after all, but from a **lot** of messages like these:

```
    {leaving hbox group (level 16) entered at line 4}
    {leaving simple group (level 15) entered at line 4}
    {leaving hbox group (level 14) entered at line 4}
    {leaving math choice group (level 13) entered at line 4}
    {entering math choice group (level 13) at line 4}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can try commenting out the bib and fixing the tex related errors and then bring in one bib item at a time to see if it is error free, and if not, fix it.

Comment: How badly formatted must your `.bib` file be to produce so large a `.log`?!  If it is (only/chiefly) due to the `.bib` file, just fix it and stop running your `.tex` file until it is done....  If EndNote has provided a faulty file, I suspect the errors are of the 'repeating' kind, and that many could be fixed through a reasonable use of search-and-replace kind of edits.

Comment: @jon I was suspecting it was from the `.bib` file, because to create it I only exported all (>15000) references from my Endnote file. The problem in fixing these errors through search-and-replace is that I want to keep both my `.bib` and Endnote libraries in sync: so whenever I update endnote, I have to export everything again, which would revert any fixes I had done in the `.bib` file before

Comment: Do you really include 15000 references in your latex file?  By the way `biblatex` has some experimental support for endnote, so there might be no need to export you endnote library to `.bib`,

Comment: @dustin ok, after doing what you suggested, I still get the log size warning. I get some errors due to the citations that are not being inserted (i.e., Texstudio is not recognizing the `\citep` commands), and a couple of errors of paragraph size (`Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)...`). Yet, this does not explain the huge log file.. Look at the edit I made in post, maybe it helps.

Comment: @Guido I'll check it out! But it seems that the error is not coming from the bibliography part (see my reply to dustin above)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LaTeX (and some packages) provide a [large array of `\tracing...` macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60491/5764). These macros include debugging information in the `.log` file that could potentially bloat the file. Remove them (either manually, or through an option within TeXStudio that has been enabled) to reduce the size of your `.log` and it will also increase the speed at which you compile.

Comment: Indeed, I had set `\tracinggroups=1` in the preamble of my document. This was producing the big list in the logs. Thanks!