# Does etoolbox's \ifboolexpr use lazy evaluation?

Tags: conditionals, etoolbox

In other words, is `bool{testB}` evaluated at all in this example code?

```
\newbool{testA}
\newbool{testB}
\booltrue{testA}
\booltrue{testB}
\ifboolexpr{ bool{testA} or bool{testB} }{OK}{Something's wrong...}
```

(I am too lazy (pun intended;)) to check in the source, the documentation seems to say nothing about it – maybe someone just *knows* that and doesn't have to analyze the source (which I did look into, but didn't understand it at a first glance)?  If it isn't something obvious, I'll be happy to do my homework, dig into the source and try to establish this.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The evaluation is *not* lazy, revealed by scanning the `.log` when [tracing the macro expansions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60491/5764):

```
%\begingroup
\tracingmacros1
\ifboolexpr{ bool{testA} or bool{testB} }{OK}{Something's wrong...}
%\endgroup
```

That is, a complete evaluation of `bool{testA}` is followed by an equivalent evaluation of `bool{testB}`, followed by an evaluation of `or`, to output `\@firstoftwo{OK}{Something's wrong...}`.

Depending on your inspection of the macro expansion, you may require the use of a group to limit the output to the `.log`.

Comment: I'd have gone for a faster route: `\ifboolexpr{ bool{testA} or bool{\ERROR} }` would work with `testA` true and lazy evaluation, but fails so evaluation can't be lazy :-)

Comment: @JosephWright: I see, the lazy approach to detecting whether the evaluation is lazy. :)

Answer (score 7):

The [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169028/4686) has been given by [Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner). [xintexpr](http://ctan.org/pkg/xint) knows about [etoolbox](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) booleans and toggles. Different syntaxes allow different levels of laziness:

[sorry I got wrong the way "lazy" was to be interpreted; thus I switch to "silly"]

1. silly: booleans are replaced by 1 or 0 depending on whether they evaluate to true or false, and then the logical `or` does not stop scanning these `1`'s or `0`'s even if it has found already a true one.
2. semi-silly: the booleans are evaluated but the `or` stops when it has found a true one
3. not silly: booleans are not evaluated unless really needed.

In the code snippet below, the three different syntaxes realize the three possibilities described above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xintexpr}

\begin{document}
\newbool{testA}
\newbool{testB}
\newbool{testC}
\booltrue{testA}
\booltrue{testB}
\booltrue{testC}

%\tracingmacros1

% silly
\xintifboolexpr{ bool(testA) | bool(testB) | bool(testC) }{OK}{Something's wrong...}

% semi-silly
\xintifboolexpr{ any(bool(testA),bool(testB),bool(testC)) }{OK}{Something's wrong...}

% not silly
\xintifboolexpr{ bool(testA)?1{bool(testB)?1{bool(testC)}} }{OK}{Something's wrong...}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I rolled-back twice my edits... `:-(` I realized I had interpreted "lazy" as the opposite of its signification in the OP, then I changed my mind, then I again changed my mind. (this is all because "lazy" has a pejorative connotation, while in fact it is the intelligent thing to do; perhaps even generally `;-)`)

Comment: With release `1.1` of `xint` (`[2014/10/28]`), the `||` for `OR` and `&&` for `AND` are preferred to  single `|` and `&`. One can also use `'or'`, `'and'`, `'xor'` (straight quotes mandatory).