# ifboolexpr with a list of toggles - true if any toggle is true

Tags: macros, conditionals, etoolbox

I'd like to write a single file with a collection of e.g. questions, but I want to produce various outputs with a different subsets of all questions each.

So at the beginning of my file I want to state which subset should be printed and I just get the according output.

I found this [**useful question**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5894/latex-conditional-expression) and came up with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

%% toggles
\newtoggle{A}
\newtoggle{B}
\newtoggle{C}

%% chosen toggle
\toggletrue{C}

\newcommand{\question}[2]{%
\ifboolexpr { #1 } { #2 }{}
}

\begin{document}

\question { togl {A} or togl {B} } {
    Question is part of subset A or subset B!
    }{}%
\question { togl {A} or togl {C} } {
    Question is part of subset A or subset C!
    }{}%    

\end{document}
```

which gets a little clumsy, the more questions and subsets I got. So I actually just want to write

```
\question { A,B } {Question is part of subset A or subset B!}%
```

Can this be done?

---

There seems to be the possibilty to use [**`any`**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169023/does-etoolboxs-ifboolexpr-use-lazy-evaluation) to expand the macro, but I can't get it work with the toggles, or at least it doesn't shorten the code.

Comment: Will there always be only 2 choices, e.g." A or B", for example, or might there be "A or B or C" or even more?

Comment: There will be more, something between 1 and 10 choices.

Comment: Do you stick to this `\ifboolexpr` stuff. I think, it could be easier with `expl3` to extend this

Comment: `etoolbox` has the means to handle csv lists so it should be doable. (I'm not at home right now so I can't test at the moment, though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short and sweet, done with recursion.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%% toggles
\newtoggle{A}
\newtoggle{B}
\newtoggle{C}
\newtoggle{D}
%% chosen toggle
\toggletrue{C}

\newcommand{\Question}[3]{%
 \def\toggletmp{F}%
 \Togl #1,\relax\relax%
 \if T\toggletmp #2\else#3\fi%
}
\def\Togl#1,#2\relax{\ifboolexpr {togl #1}%
  {\def\toggletmp{T}}%
  {\if \relax#2\relax\else\Togl#2\relax\fi}}
\begin{document}
\Question {A,B} {
    Question is part of subset A or subset B!}{Neither A nor B}\par
\Question {A,C} {
    Question is part of subset A or subset C!}{Neither A nor C}\par
\Question {C} {
    Question is part of subset C!}{Not C}\par
\Question {A,B,C,E} {
    Question is part of subset A or subset B,C,E!}{Neither A nor B, C, E}\par    
\Question {A,B,D} {
    Question is part of subset A or subset B,D!}{Neither A nor B, D}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `xparse`. You'll need to rename `\newtoggle`, `\toggletrue` and `\togglefalse` if you plan to use `etoolbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% emulate \newtoggle
\NewDocumentCommand{\newtoggle}{m}
 {
  \bool_new:c { l_twww_toggle_#1_bool }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\toggletrue}{m}
 {
  \bool_set_true:c { l_twww_toggle_#1_bool }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\togglefalse}{m}
 {
  \bool_set_false:c { l_twww_toggle_#1_bool }
 }
% evaluate booleans 
\NewDocumentCommand{\question}{mm}
 {
  \bool_if:xT { \c_false_bool \clist_map_function:nN { #1 } \twww_add_boolean:n } { #2 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \bool_if:nT { x }
\cs_new:Nn \twww_add_boolean:n
 {
  || \use:c { l_twww_toggle_#1_bool }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\newtoggle{A}
\newtoggle{B}
\newtoggle{C}

%% chosen toggle
\toggletrue{C}

\begin{document}

\question{A,B}{Question is part of subset A or subset B!}

\question{A,C}{Question is part of subset A or subset C!}

\question{A,B,C}{Question is part of subset A or subset B or subset C!}

\end{document}
```

[image]