# Execute luacode after \end{document} to rename pdf file after creation

Tags: luatex, lua, luacode

I'm using [**toggle switches**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305188/ifboolexpr-with-a-list-of-toggles-true-if-any-toggle-is-true) to create different outputs with a single tex-file. However my output PDF is always named after the producing tex-file e.g. `luaexample.tex` produces `luaexample.pdf`.

Along with the toggles I now want to create a variable

```
\def\fileID{Z}
```

which should be appended to the filename, to get e.g. `luaexampleZ.pdf`.

I thought using lua would be a create option to do so, and indeed the following almost works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\def\fileID{Z}

\begin{document}
A random number:
\begin{luacode}
tex.print(math.random())
\end{luacode}

\begin{luacode}
   os.remove("\jobname\fileID.pdf")
   os.rename("\jobname.pdf", "\jobname\fileID.pdf")
\end{luacode}

\end{document}
```

---

But the PDF due to rename is created **after** `\end{document}` but the lua code section appears **before**. If I compile the document twice, it works, but the firstly compiled PDF is renamed. I'd like to avoid this double compilation.

If I put the lua code after `\end{document}` it is not executed.

**So, how can I execute lua code or in general latex code after `\end{document}`?**

Comment: this came up before somewhere, luatex list I think, I don't think it is possible,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle using `\renewcommand`? That does not produce an output, just an aux file. But I think it would kind of crash quite a lot depending on the job name, wouldn't it? I just want to rename the final pdf, not all intermediate files. And I wouldn't know how to append a string to the `\jobname`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - my MWE? but just with double compilation, right?

Comment: @thewaywewalk: Oh yes, I didn't catch that with the double compilation

Comment: Can't be done from the 'TeX side': there is no callback executed after the PDF is closed. You have to do this by using a wrapper script to call LuaTeX (or whatever).

Comment: @JosephWright Alright, then I either use the 'lua side' as suggested by David (if it works) or just compile twice.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use the `stop_run` callback:

```
\documentclass{article}


\def\fileID{Z}

\begin{document}
A random number:


\directlua{
luatexbase.add_to_callback(
'stop_run',
function ()
 texio.write_nl("renaming output to " ..  "\jobname" .. "\fileID.pdf")
  os.rename("\jobname" .. ".pdf", "\jobname" .. "\fileID.pdf")
end,
"renamepdf"
)
}





\end{document}
```

Comment: The renaming does not work. In the office I'm still using the old luatex 0.8, if that could be the reason I'll try it tonight on another computer. I compile with texStudio `lualatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -enable-write18 %.tex`

Comment: it worked for me with 0.95  not sure if synctex would have an effect

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Doesn't work for me neither on TL16 + windows. I can rename some other file with the code, but `\jobname.pdf` doesn't change. --shell-escape or synctex doesn't matter.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer as I said in comments originally I thought I remembered reading that no callback was late enough, but this works for me (cygwin64) but of course much of the file handling at this level is in the system dependent parts of the code.

Comment: I found out, that it is absolutely essential to include `os.remove("\jobname" .. "\fileID.pdf")` before the `os.rename` in case the destination file could already exist, because the command is not executed. Maybe that's the problem for you as well @UlrikeFischer? I edit my question accordingly. The concatenation can be done directly, also. There is no need for `..`

Comment: @thewaywewalk: No the destination file didn't exist on my system (I made actually even a test with some fix name like "XXXXXX.pdf"). Also imho the callback is not meant for such manipulations and if it works it is an undocumented side-effect on which you shouldn't rely. I think it is better to start a dedicated additional run with a different jobname, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5228/can-one-tex-file-output-to-multiple-pdf-files/5265#5265

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Good to know, that you see it as undocumented behaviour. I rather don't manipulate the jobname, as it produces too much unneccesary temporary files. But with two compilation runs, the lua approach in the question just works great.

Comment: Alrigtht, on my other computer with an up-to-date miktex, it doesn't work neither.

Comment: @thewaywewalk Ok it works for me with cygwin implementation but just a two line bat file that runs luatex then moves the file would be safer anyway;-)

Comment: Could Arara move the file? System dependent, of course, but it seems to be anyway.