# Underfull \vbox - how to find offending page?

Tags: vertical-alignment, warnings

I am compiling a large latex template, [here](https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template), and always have a few underfull \vbox warnings.
I know that they're just issues with the spacing, discussion [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138/what-are-underfull-hboxes-and-vboxes-and-how-can-i-get-rid-of-them)), but is there a way to configure the warning message to tell me where the problem occurs?

That way I can easily find the problem pages, in both the PDF and the source, and decide if I need to fix it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you tried putting the `[draft]` option to your documentclass? This will mark the culprit parts in your pdf with black squares. Could be a start.

Comment: Pages are opened with a `[` in the `.log`, and closed/shipped out with a closing `<num>]`. So, you should be able to identify the shipped out page by seeing whether there's a underfull `\vbox` warning between `[` and `]`... and then check the corresponding page `<num>`.

Comment: I open the `.log` file in my text editor and search for the string "erfull" to find both over- and underfull warnings. As @Werner says, the offending page will be listed just above the warning.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi -- no black snocks for overfull vboxes; only hboxes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most commonly under- and overfull `\vbox`es are associated with pages that don't have enough or too much content on them (as they are constructed as a `v`ertical list of `box`es). So, at the page-level, you can find the offending construction by looking at your log. Here's a quick example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\tracingpages1
\tracingoutput1
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-50]
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1.1\textheight}
\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

The above code contains some dummy text followed by a single "paragraph" that is clearly bigger (vertically) than the text block (has a height of 10% more than `\textheight`). It also includes [some tracing commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60491/5764) used for debugging. The `.log` shows

```
%% goal height=550.0, max depth=5.0
% t=10.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=22.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=150 c=100000#
% t=34.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=46.0 plus 1.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=250 c=100000#
% t=58.0 plus 1.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=70.0 plus 1.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=82.0 plus 1.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=94.0 plus 1.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=106.0 plus 1.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=150 c=100000#
% t=118.0 plus 1.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=725.9478 plus 2.0 g=550.0 b=* p=150 c=*


Completed box being shipped out [10] []

%% goal height=550.0, max depth=5.0
% t=605.00336 g=550.0 b=* p=150 c=*#

Overfull \vbox (55.00336pt too high) has occurred while \output is active []



Completed box being shipped out [11] []
```

which we interpret as page `[10]` and  being shipped out without problem. Then, after page `[10]` an `Overfull \vbox` occurred. Most likely this box is associated with page `[11]` as page `[10]` was already shipped out *before* this message occurred. Tracking the page construction of page `[10]` is not all that "user-friendly", as Knuth says himself. However, we use the following interpretation from [the TeXBook](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texbook) (**Chapter 15: How TeX Makes Lines into Pages**, p 112):

> The first line, which starts with `%%`
>   is written when the first box or insertion enters the current page list;
>   it shows the `goal height` and the `max depth` that will be
>   used for that page (namely, the current values of `\vsize` and
>   `\maxdepth`). [...] dimensions in the log file are always displayed in
>   points.
>
> The subsequent lines, which start with a single `%`,
>   are written whenever a legal breakpoint is being moved from the list of
>   recent contributions to the current page list. Every `%` line shows `t`,
>   which is the total height so far if a page break were to occur,
>   and `g`, which is the goal height; in this example `g` stays fixed [...], 
>   but `g` would have decreased if insertions such as footnotes had
>   occurred on the page. The values of `t` are steadily increasing from 10 to 22 to 34, etc.; baselines are 12pt apart at the top of the page and 11pt apart at the bottom (where material is set in nine-point type).
>
> We are essentially seeing one `%` line per hbox of text being placed on
>   the current page. However, the `%` lines are generated by the penalty or
>   glue items that follow the hboxes, not by the boxes themselves. Each
>   `%` line shows also the badness `b`, the penalty `p`, and the cost `c`
>   associated with a breakpoint; if this cost is the best so far, it is
>   marked with a `#` sign, meaning that "this breakpoint will be
>   used for the current page if nothing better comes along." [Wherever you have a badness of] `b=10000`, [...] they are so bad that TeX
>   considers them indistinguishable; in such cases `c=100000`, so TeX simply
>   accumulates material until the page is full enough to
>   have `b<10000`. [...].  The notation `b=*` and
>   `c=*` on the final line means that `b` and `c` are infinite; the total
>   height [`t`] cannot be reduced to [`g`] by shrinking the
>   available glue. Therefore the page is ejected at the best previous place [...].

It's therefore obvious that while reading content for page `[10]` TeX reached a point where there the `t`otal height could not be reduced to the `g`oal height and the page was shipped out/ejected at the *previous best* break point, with that content spilling over to the subsequent page (page `[11]`). Page `[11]` only has a single, optimal (yet infinite) cost associated with the breakpoint, so the page is shipped out again... this time overfull as `605.00336pt` is `55.00336pt` too large for the `550pt` page goal.