# Compilation progress update for TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, compiling

Is there any way to turn on some sort of progress update for compilation using TikZ?  I'm working on the fireworks question on a rather slow machine (ARM chromebook) and starting to have my doubts about whether it's actually doing anything (it just sits  there saying `(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg)`).

I can write some terminal dump code and probably will, but is there anything off-the-shelf?

Comment: you can add `\tracingmacros=1` or `\tracingall` and check that the log is getting bigger (or not looping) but you may want to kill the job, tikz `tracingall` output can get _very_ big (really really very big:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see what you mean: 58kB of pdf, 1.4GB of log with `tracingmacros=1`. `tracingcommands` gave a much more reasonable 90MB. My bug was  an infinite loop -- expansion to `\foreach \x in {0,0,...360}` so the log kept growing anyway.  Scattergun `\message`s eventually did the trick.  Your comment suggests to me that this is a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60491/28808