# How \if is handled?

Tags: tex-core, conditionals

In the following example `\def\a...` fails if `\ifabc` is false and
`\myif` is not initialized before `\def\a...`.
In contrast, if `\ifabc` is true, `\myif` may be initialized before
or after `\def\a...`.

It is not clear to me why it does not fail when `\ifabc` is true and `\myif` is not initialized before `\def\a`.

```
\newif\ifabc
\abctrue % \abcfalse

%\let\myif=\iftrue

\ifabc
  \def\a#1#2{\myif#1\else#2\fi}
\fi

%\let\myif\iftrue

\ifabc
  \a{hello}{world}
\fi

\end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a supplement to [cfr's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/354123/5764).

The TeX Book mentions the following in Chapter 20 **Definitions (also called Macros)** (p 210)

> Notice that all of the control sequences for conditionals begin with `\if...`,
>   and they all have a matching `\fi`. This convention - that `\if...` pairs up with `\fi` - makes it easier to see the nesting of conditionals within your program. The nesting of `\if...\fi` is independent of the nesting of `{...}`; thus, you can begin or end a group in the middle of a conditional, and you can begin or end a conditional in the middle of a group. Extensive experience with macros has shown that such independence is important in applications; but it can also lead to confusion if you aren’t careful.

Hmmm... one should be careful. :) Note that you have a form of nested `\if...\fi` as well as grouping `{...}`.

Also (p 213):

> When an `\if...` is expanded, TeX reads ahead as far as necessary to determine whether the condition is true or false; and if false, it skips ahead (keeping track of `\if...\fi` nesting) until finding the `\else`, `\or`, or `\fi` that ends the skipped text. Similarly, when `\else`, `\or`, or `\fi` is expanded, TeX reads to the end of any text that ought to be skipped.

With the above information, we find that under `\abcfalse`, TeX "skips ahead ... until finding the `\else` ... that ends the skipped text", disregarding any grouping. As such, the expansion ends with evaluating `#2` - a macro parameter - in vertical mode.

We can also use [tracing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60491/5764) (somewhat) what is is going on:

```
 1: \documentclass{article}
 2: 
 3: \begin{document}
 4: 
 5: \newif\ifabc% Default is \abcfalse
 6: 
 7: %\let\myif=\iftrue
 8: 
 9: \tracingifs1
10: \ifabc
11:   \def\a#1#2{\myif#1\else#2\fi}
12: \fi
13: 
14: %\let\myif\iftrue
15: 
16: \ifabc
17:   \a{hello}{world}
18: \fi
19: 
20: test
21: 
22: \end{document}
```

The tracing reveals `\else` was found (still in vertical mode) as part of the `\if...` statement on line 10:

```
{vertical mode: \iffalse: (level 1) entered on line 10}
{\else: \iffalse (level 1) entered on line 10}

! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in vertical mode.
l.11   \def\a#1#2{\myif#1\else#
                               2\fi}
Sorry, but I'm not programmed to handle this case;
I'll just pretend that you didn't ask for it.
If you're in the wrong mode, you might be able to
return to the right one by typing `I}' or `I$' or `I\par'.
```

Answer (score 7):

I ***think*** ...

... that when `\abctrue`, the condition holds, so `\def` goes through. Hence, TeX doesn't try to execute the content of the `\def` until the macro is actually used.

However, when `\abcfalse`, it has to read through the content of `\def` looking for an `\else`. Since `\myif` is not known as a conditional, it doesn't realise that the `\else` is nested. Hence, it reads the stuff after the `\else` as the thing it is meant to execute, given that `\abcfalse`. And this fails because `#2` can't be used here.

Try

```
\def\a#1#2{\myif#1\else\show\super#2\fi}% but not for real - never \def a single letter macro name unless you are really, really sure you want to overwrite anything it alreay means.
```

to see that this is what is happening:

```
> \super=undefined.
l.153   \def\a#1#2{\myif#1\else\show\super
                                          #2\fi}
? 
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in vertical mode.
l.153   \def\a#1#2{\myif#1\else\show\super#
                                           2\fi}
```

In contrast, if you had `\show\super` before the `\else` and set `\abctrue`, it would never be executed unless you actually used the defined macro.