# List of figures showing id of figures not included

Tags: table-of-contents, lists, titletoc

I tried to make two separate list of figures. One for Appendix I and one for Appendix E. 
I found this code on stackexchange.com:

```
\usepackage{titletoc}
\startlist[main]{lof}% starts main list of figures
\printlist[main]{lof}{}{}% prints main list of figures

\begin{figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\end{figure}

\clearpage
\stoplist[main]{lof}% stops main list of figures

\startlist[appendix]{lof}% starts list of figures in appendices
\printlist[appendix]{lof}{}{}% prints list of figures in appendices

\stoplist[appendix]{lof}
```

The problem is, that it shows the id of the figures, that are not included:
[image]

These figures are not supposed to be in this list.
How do I avoid this?

Comment: Please convert your code into a complete document including a document class - the so called minimal working example (MWE).

Comment: @Sofie Hi and welcome to tex.se. Looks a bit as if you changed something with your packages recently. It's hard to guess without `MWE`, but did you try to delete all files `*.aux`, `*.lof`, `*.lot` and friends and rerun LaTeX?

Comment: @epR8GaYuh I'll try to remember next time :) The code is relativly massive. When I tried to make a MWE it worked perfectly. So the mistake must be somewhere else in the code.

Comment: Note that it takes two or three runs to remove things from the aux file and lof file.

Answer (score 1):

Even if this might be not a real answer to the question I'd like to provide some basics about troubleshooting (La)TeX...

One of the most important things newbies (and we all have been newbies some day...) have to learn about (La)TeX is: it's a modular system. Some things are not known when (La)TeX is run for the first time: think about references, footnotes, bibliographies, anchors, internal links, ...

So the main technique (La)TeX uses is to export data to external files which can be loaded on subsequent runs of the compiler.

The basic external file is definitely the `.aux`-file(s) since it collects almost everything (La)TeX might need in advance. A non-actual `.aux` file is the reason you get messages like `xyz changed. Rerun LaTeX to get them right.`

But there are even more depending on what packages one uses: `*.lot` for table captions, `*.lof` for figure captions and others, depending on the packages one uses.

So the basic lection(s) I personally have learned in using LaTeX for over 30 years now is:

1. Delete **all** auxiliary files. This includes folders other than the root folder in case you are using `\include`.
2. Update your (La)TeX distribiution whenever something seems to be odd.
3. Remember what you have changed **last**. Creating regular backups of your TeX-files usually help a lot especially when you are working on a project of more than 5 pages.
4. Use the same architecture (La)TeX uses. TeX and all of its derivates are modular, so `\input` and `\include` are your friends. Do **not** build monolytic blocks like in fx word (like coding 225+ macros in one file), place code snippets in subfiles to be able to track errors down once they occure.
5. This tip uses point 4: in case of trouble remove single (most of all the latest added) snippets by uncomment like `%\input`.
6. Try to minimize (also uses point 4): create a `test.tex` in the same root folder your project's `main.tex` is located and input **only** what's really needed to reproduce the error. This gives you the chance to spot cross-effects but also provides a `MWE` in case you have to ask on tex.se and friends.
7. Read the documentation. A good point to start is google with `CTAN <packagename>`. Reading documentation is sometimes frustrating especially if it's short or extremely long - but search for hints of how things are coded and, even more important, of the idea behind it.
8. Use your most valuable friends `\trace<what>` and `\show<what>`. Placing things like `\show<macro>`, `\showthe<counter or length>` or general tracing of the things that happen (see [this question for an excellent overview](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60491/latex-tracing-commands-list)) usually helps **a lot**.
9. Do not hesitate to ask. We all have had our first day with (La)TeX, we all once have reached the point of maximal frustration (or even more than once), but we all have been going on because (La)TeX is the system that provides by far the most possibilities on the market (my opinion). No one on tex.se will ever forget those moments.

I am pretty sure that others using (La)TeX and tex.se are using other techniques to trace down errors. That's ok (LoL). The list above is certainly not complete - but in might provide a starting point to newbies and sometimes a reminder to pros...