# Why does this use of `\expandafter` not work?

Tags: macros, conditionals, expansion

I've written the following code:

```
\newif\ifconsecutive
\consecutivefalse

\newcommand{\myfirst}[1]{#1\consecutivetrue\expandafter\consecutivefalse}
\newcommand{\mysecond}[1]{\ifconsecutive $\longrightarrow$\fi #1}
```

The idea was that if I write

```
\myfirst{A}\mysecond{B}
```

I get the equivalent of

```
A $\longrightarrow$ B
```

while if I type something in between, like

```
\myfirst{A} then \mysecond{B}
```

I instead get the equivalent of

```
A then B
```

The idea was that `\expandafter` would cause the text following the invocation of `\myfirst` (either an invocation of `\mysecond` or some arbitrary other code) to be expanded while `\consecutivetrue` is in effect, so if the next thing is a `\mysecond` invocation, the `\ifconsecutive` will be executed and the arrow generated, while if something else follows, it will not care about `\consecutivetrue`. After that expansion, `\consecutivefalse` should be called, causing any later invocation of `\mysecond` to not generate the arrow.

However what *actually* happens is that the arrow never gets inserted, no matter whether the macros are consecutive or not.

Now my question is: Why does this pair of macros not work as intended?

Here's a complete compilable code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifconsecutive
\consecutivefalse
\newcommand{\myfirst}[1]{#1\consecutivetrue\expandafter\consecutivefalse}
\newcommand{\mysecond}[1]{\ifconsecutive $_$\fi #1}

\begin{document}
\myfirst{A}\mysecond{B}

\myfirst{A} then \mysecond{B}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Expandafter doesn't fully expand the next token, only once. Hence, it expands `\mysecond`, executes `\consecutivefalse` and then continues with the expanded `\mysecond`. See this post for tracking/tracing LaTeX: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538/how-to-best-debug-latex

Comment: @zeroth: Thank you. Took me a bit of thinking, but finally I understood it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't want to just expand `\mysecond`, but also the `\ifconsecutive` that results, so you need three `\expandafter` tokens in front of `\consecutivefalse`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifconsecutive
\consecutivefalse
\newcommand{\myfirst}[1]{#1\consecutivetrue\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\consecutivefalse}
\newcommand{\mysecond}[1]{\ifconsecutive ${}\to\nobreak{}$\fi #1}

\begin{document}
\myfirst{A}\mysecond{B}

\myfirst{A} then \mysecond{B}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I wouldn't recommend such context sensitive macros.

A different strategy is with `\new@ifnextchar`, the version of `\@ifnextchar` provided by `amsmath` that doesn't gobble or ignore spaces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myfirst}[1]{#1\new@ifnextchar\mysecond{${}\to\nobreak{}$}{}}
\newcommand{\mysecond}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}
\myfirst{A}\mysecond{B}

\myfirst{A} \mysecond{B}

\myfirst{A} then \mysecond{B}

\myfirst{A}\relax\mysecond{B}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you (and also zeroth in the comments). I guess I was thinking too much in terms of macro "execution" instead of expansion.

Comment: @celtschk Another strategy would be to use `\@ifnextchar` at the end of `\myfirst`.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about that macro. It differs from the other solution in that following whitespace is ignored (which I consider reasonable).

Answer (score 4):

An alternative:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\mycmd[3][$\longrightarrow$]{#2 #1 #3}
\begin{document}    
\mycmd{A}{B}

\mycmd[then]{A}{B}

\end{document}
```

It is also possible to define the command as `\mycmd{A}[then]{B}`

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't answer my question. Indeed, an even simpler alternative to my example would have been to just write `A $\longrightarrow$ B` and `A then B`. But that certainly does not help understanding anything ...