# Print macros call stack

Tags: debugging

Can one print call stack of latex macros?

I want to know from where my macro is called.

Comment: Probably impossible, but there's `\errorcontextlines=100` and `tracingall` or something

Comment: [tools - How to best debug LaTeX? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538/how-to-best-debug-latex)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to best debug LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538/how-to-best-debug-latex)