# Latex debugger?

Tags: errors, compiling, compilation-error, debugging, memory

Are there any debugging capabilities in latex or any gui editors? That is, is there a way I can view the value of variables, commands, memory etc during compiling and at the exact moment compilation fails? Latex error messages are so vague and often are not enough to find what is wrong with my code.

Comment: tex messages are usually pretty accurate if you read them carefully, you can always increase `\errorcontextlines` to see more detail. `\tracingall` gives a full log of all expansions

Comment: See also [tools - How to best debug LaTeX? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538/how-to-best-debug-latex) but...

Comment: "view the value of variables, commands, memory etc" it sounds like you're not very familiar with how TeX works. Even if you're present with a debugger it wouldn't help much. If you *really* want, start with reading [package writing - Where do I start LaTeX programming? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/where-do-i-start-latex-programming?noredirect=1&lq=1) but it's a horrible programming language, I say.

Comment: @user202729 Looking at variables and commands using `\show`/`\showthe` seems a reasonable request

Comment: Maybe not really what you're after, and doesn't work for everything, but there is the lovely package [`unravel`](https://ctan.org/pkg/unravel)!

Comment: @JosephWright Was partially talking about how OP talks about "variables" and "memory" like in a typical programming language. Technically here everything are commands (kind of) and there's the concept of "input stream" but yes if it comes from someone who is good at TeX programming I'd have no problem with it