# Can I show the raw generated text from a command in my document?

Tags: formatting, verbatim, debugging, output, transformation

I am trying to debug my code and I keep running into the same problem so I would like to see what the command that causes the problem is giving to the compiler.

I have looked for this and I can't seem to find someone who asked this question.

So is there a command or environment that would treat the result of a function as verbatim
like this? `\verboutput{\mycommand}`

Comment: In TeX `\show\mycommand` would write the definition of `\mycommand` to the terminal and the log. In LaTeX it would be better to use `\ShowCommand\mycommand`, because it also handles the different kinds of protected commands. See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4327/where-do-i-find-out-how-a-command-environment-is-defined

Comment: `\texttt{\mycommand}`, `\typeout{\mycommand}` or `\showtokens\expandafter{\mycommand}` or `\typeout{\meaning\mycommand}` etc. depends on what you mean. See also [tools - How to best debug LaTeX? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538/how-to-best-debug-latex?noredirect=1&lq=1) -- although it's true that a debugging guide is kind of missing.